# How to emulate a do-while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

I need to emulate a do-while loop in a Python program. Unfortunately, the following straightforward code does not work:

```
list_of_ints = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
iterator = list_of_ints.__iter__()
element = None

while True:
  if element:
    print element

  try:
    element = iterator.next()
  except StopIteration:
    break

print "done"
```

Instead of "1,2,3,done", it prints the following output:

```
[stdout:]1
[stdout:]2
[stdout:]3
None['Traceback (most recent call last):
', '  File "test_python.py", line 8, in <module>
    s = i.next()
', 'StopIteration
']
```

What can I do in order to catch the 'stop iteration' exception and break a while
loop properly?

An example of why such a thing may be needed is shown below as pseudocode.

State machine:

```
s = ""
while True :
  if state is STATE_CODE :
    if "//" in s :
      tokens.add( TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] )
      state = STATE_COMMENT
    else :
      tokens.add( TOKEN_CODE, s )
  if state is STATE_COMMENT :
    if "//" in s :
      tokens.append( TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] )
    else
      state = STATE_CODE
      # Re-evaluate same line
      continue
  try :
    s = i.next()
  except StopIteration :
    break
```

Comment: Um... That's not a proper "do-while"; that's simply a "do-forever".  What's wrong with "while True" and "break"?

Comment: S. Lott: I'm pretty sure his question was about *how* to implement do while in python. So, I wouldn't expect his code to be completely correct. Also, he is very close to a do while... he is checking a condition at the end of the "forever" loop to see if he should break out. It's not "do-forever".

Comment: so ... your initial example code actually works for me with no problem and i don't get that traceback. that's a proper idiom for a do while loop where the break condition is iterator exhaustion. typically, you'd set `s=i.next()` rather than None and possibly do some initial work rather than just make your first pass through the loop useless though.

Comment: @underrun Unfortunately, the post is not tagged with which version of Python was being used - the original snippet works for me too using 2.7, presumably  due to updates to the Python language itself.

Answer (score 1296, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. You can implement a do-while loop like this:

```
while True:
  stuff()
  if fail_condition:
    break
```

Or:

```
stuff()
while not fail_condition:
  stuff()
```

What are you doing trying to use a do while loop to print the stuff in the list? Why not just use:

```
for i in l:
  print i
print "done"
```

Update:

So do you have a list of lines? And you want to keep iterating through it? How about:

```
for s in l: 
  while True: 
    stuff() 
    # use a "break" instead of s = i.next()
```

Does that seem like something close to what you would want? With your code example, it would be:

```
for s in some_list:
  while True:
    if state is STATE_CODE:
      if "//" in s:
        tokens.add( TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] )
        state = STATE_COMMENT
      else :
        tokens.add( TOKEN_CODE, s )
    if state is STATE_COMMENT:
      if "//" in s:
        tokens.append( TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] )
        break # get next s
      else:
        state = STATE_CODE
        # re-evaluate same line
        # continues automatically
```

Comment: i need to create a state machine. In state machine it's a normal case to re-evaluate CURRENT statement, so i need to 'continue' without iterating next item. I don't know how to do such thing in 'for s in l:' iteration :(. In do-while loop, 'continue' will re-evaluate current item, iteration at end

Comment: Do you mean you need to keep track of your place in the list? That way when you return the same state, you can pick up where you left off? Give a bit more context. It seems like you might be better off using an index into the list.

Comment: Thanks, I commented on your pseudocode... your example seems sort of bad since you seem to handle "//" the same way no matter what state you are in. Also, is this real code where you are processing comments? What if you have strings with slashes? ie:

print "blah // <-- does that mess you up?"

Comment: That was a sample pseudocode, just to illustrate a concept why it is needed to process same line more than once. But your sample with for ... + While True seems VERY good to me and solves the exact task i have: 'break' goes to next item and 'continue' re-evaluates same item.

Comment: I like the `while True: stuff(); if fail_condition: break` idea. Very nice!

Comment: It's a shame that python does not have a do-while loop. Python is DRY, eh ?

Comment: Also see [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) for the official stance/justification: "Users of the language are advised to use the while-True form with an inner if-break when a do-while loop would have been appropriate."

Comment: While [PEP 315](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) might seem related, that proposal is not for a do while loop as found in most other languages:  looped statements both precede and follow the while statement.  No wonder it was rejected.

Answer (score 398):

Here's a very simple way to emulate a do-while loop:

```
condition = True
while condition:
    # loop body here
    condition = test_loop_condition()
# end of loop
```

The key features of a do-while loop are that the loop body always executes at least once, and that the condition is evaluated at the bottom of the loop body.  The control structure show here accomplishes both of these with no need for exceptions or break statements.  It does introduce one extra Boolean variable.

Comment: It doesn't always add an extra boolean variable. Often there's something(s) that already exist whose state can be tested.

Comment: The reason I like this solution the most is that it doesn't add another condition, it still is just one cycle, and if you pick a good name for the helper variable the whole structure is quite clear.

Comment: NOTE: While this does address the original question, this approach is less flexible than using `break`. Specifically, if there is logic needed AFTER `test_loop_condition()`, that should not be executed once we are done, it has to be wrapped in `if condition:`. BTW, `condition` is vague. More descriptive: `more` or `notDone`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I disagree. I rarely use `break` in loops and when I encounter it in code that I maintain I find that the loop, most often, could have been written without it. The presented solution is, IMO, the *clearest* way to represent a do while construct in python.

Comment: Ideally, condition will be named something descriptive, like `has_no_errors` or `end_reached` (in which case the loop would start `while not end_reached`

Comment: this causes pylint C0103 error, due to condition being considered a constant?

Comment: But what if condition is lengthy? say a very long one liner

Comment: @LukeGriffith Ideally you wouldn't use this outside of a function so condition is coming back as a constant. From another answer: 'avoid module level variables, by wrapping them into a function.' at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204932/python-pylint-c0103invalid-constant-name

Comment: @MitchellWalls: Wrapping them in functions to avoid what's essentially a bug in PyLint is a terrible suggestion.

Comment: @martineau Explain to me how this is a PyLint bug? I don't see it. My mostly naive assessment to the original comment is to say yes use functions it is a good habit. I don't see how this "is a terrible suggestion". Please be more helpful and explain.

Comment: @MitchellWalls: PEP 8 does not say that all module level variables should be capitalized, only those that are [constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants). Actually it's more of a limitation of static code checking (rather than a bug) — it would be very difficult for it to determine the variable's intent. That means that wrapping them in functions would be doing nothing but introduce overhead to get around a limitation of the tool. See the comments under this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217309/355230), especially the one about how it obfuscates code.

Comment: @nurettin Because the code presented will always execute the loop body at least once, *before* checking `test_loop_condition()`.

Answer (score 101):

My code below might be a useful implementation, highlighting the main difference between [do-while](/questions/tagged/do-while) vs [while](/questions/tagged/while) as I understand it.

So in this one case, you always go through the loop at least once.

```
first_pass = True
while first_pass or condition:
    first_pass = False
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Correct answer, I'de argue. Plus it avoids **break**, for safe use in try/except blocks.

Comment: does the jit/optimizer avoid re-testing first_pass after the first pass?  otherwise, it would be an annoying, though perhaps minor, performance issue

Comment: @markhahn this is really minor but if you care of such details, you can intervert the 2 booleans in the loop: `while condition or first_pass:`. Then `condition`is always evaluated first and overall `first_pass` is evaluated only twice (first and last iteration). Don't forget to initialize `condition` before the loop to whatever you want.

Comment: HM, interesting I actually had picked the other way round purposely to not have to initialise condition and thus requiring minimal changes to the code. That said I see your point

Comment: The problem here is that first_pass is set to `False` in every loop now.

Comment: @AkhilNambiar There's no problem with that? It's not the first pass... after the first pass.

Comment: for a simple loop, the loop overhead (testing conditions) will be a significant part of the cost.  in that case, it's a major win if condition is first, since first_pass will only be useful the first time.  the optimizer could notice this (and eliminate spurious tests as well as spurious assignments), but I suspect it doesn't try to do this kind of "theorem proving".  OTOH, if evaluating condition is expensive, and the expected loop count is low, this really doesn't matter...

Answer (score 39):

```
do {
  stuff()
} while (condition())
```

->

```
while True:
  stuff()
  if not condition():
    break
```

You can do a function:

```
def do_while(stuff, condition):
  while condition(stuff()):
    pass
```

But
1) It's ugly.
2) Condition should be a function with one parameter, supposed to be filled by stuff (it's the only reason *not* to use the classic while loop.)

Comment: Writing `while True: stuff(); if not condition(): break` is a very good idea. Thank you!

Comment: @ZeD, why is 1) ugly?
It's quite Ok, IMHO

Comment: @SergeyLossev It's going to be difficult to grasp the logic of the program because it appears as a infinite loop at first, if you have a lot of 'stuff' code in between.

Answer (score 35):

Exception will break the loop, so you might as well handle it outside the loop.

```
try:
  while True:
    if s:
      print s
    s = i.next()
except StopIteration:   
  pass
```

I guess that the problem with your code is that behaviour of `break` inside `except` is not defined. Generally `break` goes only one level up, so e.g. `break` inside `try` goes directly to `finally` (if it exists) an out of the `try`, but not out of the loop.

Related PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136 
Related question: [Breaking out of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops)

Comment: It's good practice though to only have inside the try statement what you expect to throw your exception, lest you catch unwanted exceptions.

Comment: Writing code to expect exceptions is a poor programming practice, and in many JITed languages (I know, python is not JITed, but you don't want to get into the habit), it results in horrid performance.

Comment: @PiPeep: no problem, just keep in mind, that what's true for some languages, may not be true for other. Python is optimized for intensive use of exceptions.

Comment: break and continue are perfectly well-defined in any clause of a try/except/finally statement. They simply ignore them, and either break out of or move on to the next iteration of the containing while or for loop as appropriate. As components of the looping constructs, they're only relevant to while and for statements, and trigger a syntax error if they run into a class or def statement before reaching the innermost loop. They ignore if, with and try statements.

Comment: all this machinery to emulate a simple `do while`.  Why does python lack these things?

Comment: This answer is best because it actually points out what is wrong with the OP's code

Comment: @javadba The reason for that is actually quite the opposite: Why do other languages feel the need to use `do while` loops? They are never useful, as the only difference between `do while` and `while` is whether the statements within the block are executed at least once.

Comment: .. which is an important case

Comment: @1313e One common use case is retrieving paginated results of a query: If this is the first page of results, or a previous page of results indicated that there are more results to fetch, fetch another page of results.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Because it doesn't have to be this complicated.  The idiomatic way is `while True: do_stuff(); if condition: break`.

Comment: @BlackJack Which is a lousy construct vs other languages.  `python` has been my primary language for 3 years (due to data science libraries only available in this language) and I have done heavy duty projects for the prior 8 years.  i'm no noobie at all - but the language *is* weak . The main positive is `numpy` and its array indexing

Comment: Lousy is a bit harsh and uncalled for. It is almost like a DO … WHILE or DO … UNTIL loop in other languages.  The difference is really minor.

Answer (score 18):

The way I've done this is as follows...

```
condition = True
while condition:
     do_stuff()
     condition = (<something that evaluates to True or False>)
```

This seems to me to be the simplistic solution, I'm surprised I haven't seen it here already. This can obviously also be inverted to

```
while not condition:
```

etc.

Comment: You say "I'm surprised I haven't seen it here already" - but I don't see any difference from, let's say, powderflask's solution from 2010. It's exactly the same.

    ("condition = True
    while condition:
        # loop body here
        condition = test_loop_condition()
   # end of loop")

Answer (score 18):

I believe that this do-while simulation on python has a syntax format closest to the do-while structure format present in C and Java.

```py
do = True
while do:
    [...]
    do = <condition>
```

Comment: why not use simply `do = <condition>` ?

Comment: @lenik `do = <condition>` does not truely emulate a `do ... while` loop

Comment: @soulmachine Why not?

Comment: Because a `do ... while` loop runs the first iteration unconditionally, always, and only evaluates the condition before the next iterations.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a crazier solution of a different pattern -- using coroutines. The code is still very similar, but with one important difference; there are no exit conditions at all! The coroutine (chain of coroutines really) just stops when you stop feeding it with data.

```
def coroutine(func):
    """Coroutine decorator

    Coroutines must be started, advanced to their first "yield" point,
    and this decorator does this automatically.
    """
    def startcr(*ar, **kw):
        cr = func(*ar, **kw)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return startcr

@coroutine
def collector(storage):
    """Act as "sink" and collect all sent in @storage"""
    while True:
        storage.append((yield))

@coroutine      
def state_machine(sink):
    """ .send() new parts to be tokenized by the state machine,
    tokens are passed on to @sink
    """ 
    s = ""
    state = STATE_CODE
    while True: 
        if state is STATE_CODE :
            if "//" in s :
                sink.send((TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] ))
                state = STATE_COMMENT
            else :
                sink.send(( TOKEN_CODE, s ))
        if state is STATE_COMMENT :
            if "//" in s :
                sink.send(( TOKEN_COMMENT, s.split( "//" )[1] ))
            else
                state = STATE_CODE
                # re-evaluate same line
                continue
        s = (yield)

tokens = []
sm = state_machine(collector(tokens))
for piece in i:
    sm.send(piece)
```

The code above collects all tokens as tuples in `tokens` and I assume there is no difference between `.append()` and `.add()` in the original code.

Comment: How would you write this in Python 3.x today?

Answer (score 10):

Python 3.8 has the answer.

It's called assignment expressions. from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```py
# Loop over fixed length blocks
while (block := f.read(256)) != '':
    process(block)
```

Comment: Nope.  `do` _body_ `while` _condition_  first executes the _body_ and then evaluates the _condition_.  your construct first checks the condition.  it's a while ... do loop.

Comment: I would prefer using `functools.partial()` and `iter()` for this: `for block in iter(partial, file.read, 256), ""): process(block)`.

Comment: A better solution would be: `do = True; while do: ; something(); if (do := condition()): complain();`

Comment: This is the tipical example where you run the code in the "while" statement, therefore is similar to the do/while. On top with this, you might get the output. I would use this and put the required to run once in the function evaluated by while and the rest after.

Answer (score 8):

for a do - while loop containing try statements

```
loop = True
while loop:
    generic_stuff()
    try:
        questionable_stuff()
#       to break from successful completion
#       loop = False  
    except:
        optional_stuff()
#       to break from unsuccessful completion - 
#       the case referenced in the OP's question
        loop = False
   finally:
        more_generic_stuff()
```

alternatively, when there's no need for the 'finally' clause

```
while True:
    generic_stuff()
    try:
        questionable_stuff()
#       to break from successful completion
#       break  
    except:
        optional_stuff()
#       to break from unsuccessful completion - 
#       the case referenced in the OP's question
        break
```

Comment: The use of `try` here is not justifiable.

Answer (score 8):

**While loop:**

```
while condition:
  print("hello")
```

**Do while loop:**

```
while True:
  print("hello")
  if not condition:
    break
```

**Also you can use any true boolean value as condition:**

```
while 1:
  print("hello")
  if not condition:
    break
```

**Another variant:**

```
check = 1
while check:
    print("hello")
    check = condition
```

Answer (score 6):

Quick hack:

```
def dowhile(func = None, condition = None):
    if not func or not condition:
        return
    else:
        func()
        while condition():
            func()
```

Use like so:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> def f():
...     global x
...     x = x - 1
>>> def c():
        global x
        return x > 0
>>> dowhile(f, c)
>>> print x
0
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just do

```
for s in l :
    print s
print "done"
```

?

Comment: i need to create a state machine. In state machine it's a normal case to re-evaluate CURRENT statement, so i need to 'continue' without iterating next item. I don't know how to do such thing in 'for s in l:' iteration :(. In do-while loop, 'continue' will re-evaluate current item, iteration at end.

Comment: then, can you define some pseudo-code for your state machine, so we can hint you towards the best pythonic solution ? I don't know much about state machines(and am probably not the only one), so if you tell us a bit about your algorithm, this will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: For loop does not work for things like: a = fun() while a == 'zxc': sleep(10) a = fun()

Comment: This completely misses the point of checking a boolean condition

Answer (score 4):

```
while condition is True: 
  stuff()
else:
  stuff()
```

Comment: Ew. That seems significantly uglier than using a break.

Comment: That is clever, but it requires `stuff` to be a function or for the code body to be repeated.

Comment: All that's needed is `while condition:` because `is True` is implied.

Comment: this fails if `condition` depends on some inner variable of `stuff()`, because that variable is not defined at that moment.

Comment: Not the same logic, because on the last iteration when condition != True : It calls the code a final time. Where as a ***Do While***, calls the code once first, then checks condition before re-running. Do While : **execute block once; then check and re-run**, this answer: **check and re-run; then execute code block once**. Big difference!

Answer (score 1):

You wondered:

> **What can I do in order to catch the 'stop iteration' exception and break a while loop properly?**

You could do it as shown below and which also makes use of the [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) feature (aka “the walrus operator”) that was introduced in Python 3.8:

```
list_of_ints = [1, 2, 3]
iterator = iter(list_of_ints)

try:
    while (element := next(iterator)):
        print(element)
except StopIteration:
    print("done")
```

Another possibility (that would work from Python 2.6 to 3.x) would be to  provide a *`default`* argument to the built-in [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to avoid the `StopIteration` exception:

```
SENTINEL = object()  # Unique object.
list_of_ints = [1, 2, 3]
iterator = iter(list_of_ints)

while True:
    element = next(iterator, SENTINEL)
    if element is SENTINEL:
        break
    print(element)

print("done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean things up a bit with the walrus operator in Python 3.8:

```
list_of_ints = [ 1, 2, None, 3 ]
iterator = iter(list_of_ints)

_sentinel = object()
while True:
    if (i := next(iterator, _sentinel)) is _sentinel:
        break

    print(i)
```

This has no duplicated logic outside the `while`. It also handles values in the list that evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [evan54's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095765/1725562):

With defining a helper class

```
class FirstAccess:
    def __init__(self):
        self._accessed = False

    def __bool__(self):
        if self._accessed:
            return False
        self._accessed = True
        return True
```

one can save the update of the flag in the loop body, because it gets updated by accessing it:

```
first_pass = FirstAccess()
while first_pass or condition:
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps :

Set a flag inside the exception handler and check it before working on the s.

```
flagBreak = false;
while True :

    if flagBreak : break

    if s :
        print s
    try :
        s = i.next()
    except StopIteration :
        flagBreak = true

print "done"
```

Comment: Could be simplified by using `while not flagBreak:` and removing the `if (flagBreak) : break`.

Comment: I avoid variables named `flag`--I am unable to infer what a True value or False value mean. Instead, use `done` or `endOfIteration`. The code turns into `while not done: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a scenario where you are looping while a resource is unavaliable or something similar that throws an exception, you could use something like

```
import time

while True:
    try:
       f = open('some/path', 'r')
    except IOError:
       print('File could not be read. Retrying in 5 seconds')   
       time.sleep(5)
    else:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a typical while loop will be something like this:

```
xBool = True
# A counter to force a condition (eg. yCount = some integer value)

while xBool:
    # set up the condition (eg. if yCount > 0):
        (Do something)
        yCount = yCount - 1
    else:
        # (condition is not met, set xBool False)
        xBool = False
```

I could include a *for..loop* within the while loop as well, if situation so warrants, for looping through another set of condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        # stuff
        stuff_1()
        if some_cond:
            continue
        if other_cond:
            break
        stuff_2()
    finally:
        # condition
        if not condition:
            break
```

- [x] `condition` checked only after running `stuff`
- [x] `stuff` is not a function call
- [x] `condition` is not a function call
- [x] `stuff` can contain flow control
- [ ] Avoid checking `condition` if `stuff` called `break` (can be done with another boolean)

Comment: The use of `try...finally` is not justified here.

Answer (score -2):

The built-in [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter) function does specifically that:

```
for x in iter(YOUR_FN, TERM_VAL):
    ...
```

E.g. (tested in Py2 and 3):

```
class Easy:
  X = 0
  @classmethod
  def com(cls):
    cls.X += 1
    return cls.X

for x in iter(Easy.com, 10):
  print(">>>", x)
```

If you want to give a condition to terminate instead of a value, you always can set an equality, and require that equality to be `True`.