# Parallel.ForEach finally clause

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I would like to know if there is maybe a `finally` that i can use in a `Parallel.ForEach`?

```
try
{
}
finally
{
}
```

Is this possible in a `Parallel.ForEach`?

**I need to do a finally when the loop has completed.**

```
Parallel.ForEach(someList, x =>
{
    //...
}, // Now i need to do a finally);
```

My problem is that i have a try finally around my Parallel.ForEach, but i dont want the finally to happen. It must only happen when the parallel task has completed.

So this does not work for me:

```
try
{
   Parallel.ForEach(someList, x =>
   {
      //...
   });
}
finally
{
}
```

Is there maybe another way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loops and `finally` don't go together (except maybe in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743164/21567)). You simply write the code to run after the loop, well, after the loop.

If you want to run it regardless of exceptions in the loop, do it like this:

```
try
{
   Parallel.ForEach(...)
}
finally
{
   // ...
}
```

On second thought, maybe the OP ment to use this Parallel.ForEach [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx), which allows you to provide a "localFinal" action, that is invoked whenever a thread (used to execute one more iterations of the loop) has completed.

Comment: As a bit of explanation, the reason this works is that `Parallel.ForEach` blocks the current thread until all operations are complete, unlike, e.g., starting a thread, which returns control immediately.

Comment: Sorry, but it is quite unclear what you mean by "I don't want the finally to happen" or by "when the task is completed". (1) if you don't want a finally, don't write one. (2) You use the `Parallel` class to abstract from the `Task` class (assuming you're actually referring to that).

Comment: Your second thought is correct. =) So there is an overload for this? Do you perhaps have an example for me?

Comment: @Willem check the MSDN page I linked to. They provide an example at/near the bottom

Answer (score 2):

You either put a `try .. finally` block inside the action being performed in parallel, or outside it:

```
Parallel.ForEach(someList, x =>
{
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
    }
});
```

or:

```
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(someList, x =>
    {
    });
}
finally
{
}
```

It depends on your use case, which isn't clear from the question.

Comment: In that case, the latter case works - see Tim S's comment to Christian K's answer.