# Pythonic do-while loop

Tags: python, do-while

While python doesn't explicitly allow do-while loops, there are at least 3 reasonable ways to implement them:

1)

```
while True:
    #loop body
    if not expr():
        break
```

2)

```
x = True
while x:
    #loop body
    x = expr()
```

3)

```
def f():
    #loop body

f()
while expr():
    f()
```

Not to mention other methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/do-while-loop-in-python) (e.g. coroutines, try-except clauses, iterators, etc), that I assume are non-pythonic under most conditions. I even see some answers arguing that do-while loops are non-pythonic, but I don't know a generic alternative.

Which method is most pythonic? They all have their oddity: 1) begins with an infinite loop, 2) creates a opaque variable at first, and 3) defines a new function. Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: this will get closed since its subjective ... but 2 is the most pythonic imho

Comment: I think this really depends a lot on how `expr` is actually implemented and what you want out of it.

Comment: Slight tangent: there was long discussion on python-list recently about a proposed [new syntax](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-October/633761.html) to replace all of these. It seems unlikely to go anywhere, though.

Comment: higher-order `dowhile` function?

Comment: There are two responses to the "while expression" (which is actually a statement… but never mind that) post that @ZeroPiraeus linked that directly say that #1 is the idiomatic way, and explain why…

Comment: Almost everything is subjective but experienced programmers will articulate reasons which readers can apply to their own situations in order to choose the appropriate variation.

Comment: Thanks for indicating where the answer to this question may be found @barnert. Unfortunately, that link from Zero Piraeus is now 404, so we may never know. Where does SO recommend the answers to closed questions should be kept?