# C++ to python beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am totally new to python and I have this code snippet of c++ :

```
do
    {
    cout << "Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ";
    cin >> input ;
    } while((input.length()) != 12 );
```

How do I change this part to python ? I have tried this so far , I don't get what the right syntax or logic flow it will be . This is what I have :

```
while True:
  print("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ")
  input = raw_input()
  check = len(input)
  if check != 12
  break
```

**The above part is solved !**

Also , another c++ snippet that is : **input is string**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++)
    {
     code[i] = input.at(i) - '0';
    }
```

I cannot figure out how to change this part to python code

```
code[i] = input.at(i) - '0';
```

So, the problem i am having is I can't figure out how to initialize the array

```
int code[12] ;
```

How should that be in python so the i can execute this piece of code ! as given :

```
   int code[12] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++)
      {
        code[i] = input.at(i) - '0';
      }
```

Comment: Note that 'translating' code from one language to another doesn't really work well, as things that make a lot of sense in one language can be inefficient and unreadable in another.

Comment: Also, if you have two questions, please post them separately instead of tacking it on to a question. It will get more people to answer, and make it more useful as a resource for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, [do..while is not in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/do-while-loop-in-python)

For your first question:

```
while True:
  print "Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : "
  x = input()

  if len(str(x)) == 12:
    break
```

Python is sensitive to whitespace, and the methods are managed with tabs and spaces instead of brackets. Also you were missing a colon.

For your second question, the code looks like you're taking the character and converting it into the digit. You can simply do a type cast:

```
for i in range(12):
  code[i] = int(x[i])
```

Comment: how should I initialize the code array ? or we don't do that in python ?

Answer (score 3):

For the first code snippet, you can change:

```
print("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12: ")
input = raw_input()
```

To:

```
input = raw_input("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12: ")
```

You also don't need the `check` variable, instead just do:

```
if len(input) == 12:
  break
```

Notice how after the IF statement I include an `:` (the equality test must also be `==`, not `!=`). Then, anything further indented after the decision is executed if the condition is `True`.

For the second code snippet, you can convert from integer to string (and string to integer) using the `int()` and `str()` functions. E.g.

```
>>> a = '012345678912'
>>> len(a) == 12
True
>>> b = int(a)
>>> print b
12345678912
>>> str(b)
'12345678912'
```

Comment: how can i initialize an array ? like int code[12] and then carry out the 2nd part ?

Comment: You can create an array using: `myList = []`. Then use the `.append()` function (i.e. `myList.append(3)`) to add items to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
do
    {
    cout << "Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ";
    cin >> input ;
    } while((input.length()) != 12 );

int code[12] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++)
        {
        code[i] = input.at(i) - '0';
        }
```

translates to

```
while True:
    input = raw_input("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ")
    if len(input) == 12:
         break
code = []
for ind in range(0,12):
    code.append(ord(input[ind]) - ord('0'))
```

There are simpler ways of parsing a string of digits to their constituent values in python, such as

```
code.append(int(input[ind]))
```

the translation I've provided is agnostic to the purpose of the code [could include letters etc] though

the variable 'code' in the python is a list rather than an array of course