# Pythonic way of doing this?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep

I have this code construct:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    do_something()
    if some_condition:
        flag = False
```

Is it the best way to do that? Or is there a better pythonic way?

Comment: I think you can use `break` here :o

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/do-while-loop-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while True:
    do_something()
    if some_condition: break
```

or

```
while not some_condition:
    do_something()
```

For the second option to be equivalent to the first, `some_condition` must start as `False` so `do_something()` will get called at least once.

Answer (score 1):

```
def late(cond):
    yield None
    while cond(): yield None

for _ in late(lambda: condition):
    do_something()
```

Looks weird. What happens here?

The `late()` generator forst yields a value in order to enter the loop unconditionally. And in every successive loop run, the `cond()` is checked.