# Run while loop one extra time after condition is met

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I am making an area calculator to help me understand the basics of Python, but I want to do some type of validation on it - if a length is less than zero, then ask again.
I've managed to do this with the 'validation' code inside the function for the shape (e.g. inside the 'square' function) but when I put the validation code in a separate function - 'negativeLength,' it doesn't work. This is my code in the separate function:

```
def negativeLength(whichOne):
    while whichOne < 1:
        whichOne = int(input('Please enter a valid length!'))
```

When I run this by calling 'negativeLength(Length)' it will ask me for the length again (as it should) but when I enter the positive length, the condition is met and so the actual loop does not run.

I have also tried (after following [Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/do-while-loop-in-python))

```
def negativeLength(whichOne):
    while True:
        whichOne = int(input('Please enter a valid length!'))
        if whichOne < 1:
            break
```

... but that doesn't work either.

I've put the parameter as 'whichOne' because the circle's 'length' is called Radius, so I'd call it as negativeLength(Radius) instead of negativeLength(Length) for a square.

So is there any way to make the while loop finish after the 'whichOne = int(input...)'?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.3.3

Comment: It's helpful to see exactly what the code you're calling this from looks like. I suspect you're attempting to pass `Length` and `Radius` by reference, so that they're never actually getting set.

Comment: @bytbox This is what I'm calling it from: `print('What is the length of one of the sides for your square, in cm?')
       Length = int(input())
        negativeLength(Length)
        Area = Length * Length
        return Area`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written works, as far as it goes. However, it won't actually do anything useful, because `whichOne` is never returned to the caller of the function. Note that

```
def f(x):
    x = 2

x = 1
f(x)
print(x)
```

will print 1, not 2. You want to do something like this:

```
def negative_length(x):
    while x < 0:
        x = int(input('That was negative. Please input a non-negative length:'))
    return x

x = input('Enter a length:')
x = negative_length(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that you could call a function as well as define it at the same time - you really helped, how do I mark this as answered? This is my first time in stackoverflow

Comment: @shub I didn't even know how - had to look it up :) But it looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using Python 3.  If not, you need to use raw_input() rather than input().

The code that I usually use for this would look like:

```
def negativeLength():
    user_input = raw_input('Please enter a length greater than 1: ')
    if int(user_input) > 1:
        return user_input
    input_chk = False
    while not input_chk:
        user_input = raw_input('Entry not valid.  Please enter a valid length: ')
        if int(user_input) > 1:
            input_chk = True
    return user_input
```

Which should do what you want.