# DO-WHILE loop in Cython

Tags: cython, do-while

Does anyone know how to represent the do..while in Cython?

Ex:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm

Comment: I can't see any evidence from the Cython reference that this is supported. But I didn't look very hard. You should read it now: if it's there, you can do it; if it's not, you can't.

Comment: `while ... if ... break` is the usual Python equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, I think does not exist. However it is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, and most importantly, **Cython** supports `for` and `while` loops as found in **Python** without modification.

Secondly, **Python** does **not** have a `do-while` implementation. Hence, given the above, you can not `do-while` in **Cython**.

You can, however, achieve the same result, as expressed in this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python).

Finally, remember that there is magic in getting the most out of **Cython**. For example, if you are looping over a range call, you will probably want to type the range argument as a **C int**. If you are looping over a **Python** container, statically typing the loop indexing variable may well introduce additional overhead. Kurt W Smith's excellent **Cython** is a worthwhile read if you are really going to get under the hood.