# <Python> while statement if the condition is in itself

Tags: python

```
while (/*condition include a*/):
    //for some reason has to create a in the process.
```

Recently I encountered a python program which has to be built that way. Finally I switched the method and avoid the problem. But it got me thinking what if we need a while statement but the condition of that statement is in the excution process of the statement. And it will give an error when we run it like a is not defined. So what can we do to make that work. I know it's a easy problem, I am a beginner so please help me if you want to, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about do-while loop when the first iteration should be executed anyway and then should be checked. If I am correct there is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python) on this topic on SO already.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly how was your problem but I think could do this

```
a = True
while a and other_conditions:
    a = get_a_value()
    # rest of the code
```

In this case I used boolean values, but `a` could take any value that doesn't affect the general condition (Like 1 in multiplication, or 0 for sums)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you simply need to initialize `a` to a value which will force the `while` loop to make at least one iteration. A very simple example:

```
a = 0
while a < 5:
    a += 1
```

Comment: Yes perhaps I simplified the situation too much.

Comment: The real situation is I have to initiate a list then append element to it.and then I tried to initiate a=[], but the condition check is need to check all the a[1],a[2],a[3], but if I only initiate an empty list it will still give me an error. And I if I initiate a = [ , , , ] with 4 empty elements, then after I append , I will have 8 element and it's not good. Finally I give up appending and just change the value of empty elements. But is there an easy way to use "do-while loop when the first iteration should be executed anyway and then should be checked"?

Comment: What *exactly* do you have to check? Something like `while any(predicate, a):` or `while all(predicate, a):` (where `predicate` is some Boolean function you can apply to each element of the list) may be what you want.

Comment: In general, you need to do two (related) things: initialize `a` to *some* list that can be checked, and generalized your check to handle a list whose size you don't know in advance.