# How to pythonically avoid this code duplication with a while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, code-duplication

I want to find the first filename `myfile????.txt` that doesn't exist yet (`????`  is a number). This works:

```
import os
i = 0
f = 'myfile%04i.txt' % i
while os.path.exists(f):
    i += 1
    f = 'myfile%04i.txt' % i
```

but I don't like the code duplication of `f = ...`.

**Is there a pythonic way to avoid the code duplication in this `while` loop?**

NB: I have posted a half-satisfactory solution, using a `do/while` idiom, as mentioned in the main answer of [Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python), but I still wonder if there is better way for this particular case (thus, it's not a dupe of this question).

Comment: `glob.glob` with some `regex` would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: A nice solution is coming next year: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to follow the `while` paradiagm here, a nested generator expression with `next()` works:

```
import os
from itertools import count
f = next(f for f in ('myfile%04i.txt' % i for i in count()) if not os.path.exists(f))
print(f)
```

Comment: Perfect solution (I just edited so that we can easily test it by copying/pasting).

Comment: @Basj ok, note I just edited it a bit to correct a mistake (of mine)

Comment: This is really pythonic, concise, and explicit! I thought it would be possible with a generator / next() but I didn't find how to do it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `f` variable.

```
import os

i = 0
while os.path.exists('myfile%04i.txt' % i):
    i += 1
```

Comment: Oh great! But I still need `f` at the end, is there a way to get it?

Comment: Make `f` a variable and "give" it to `while`.

Comment: @Basj Yes, you could still initialize `f` before the loop, then use `while os.path.exists(f % i)`

Comment: The second solution doesn't work, if you `print f`, you'll get `myfile%04i.txt` and not `myfile0002.txt` for example. So we would need to add `f = f % i` at the end to really get the answer in `f`. It's probably the best solution so far though!

Comment: Ah, you're right. My bad for not running it. I'm going to revert my edit, since that's essentially what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

I nearly found the answer *while* writing the end of the question. After a few modifications, it works:

```
import os
i = 0
while True:
    f = 'myfile%04i.txt' % i
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        break
    i += 1
print f
```

Still I wonder if there is a more pythonic way, maybe with an iterator, generator, `next(...)` or anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this too simple?

```
import os
f = 'myfile0000.txt'
while os.path.exists(f):
    i += 1
    f = 'myfile%04i.txt' % i
```

Comment: It "works", like my question's code, and the solution I posted, but I wanted to know if there is a solution without duplication of `f = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import os
from itertools import count

cursor = count()
it = iter((path for path in map(lambda x: 'myfile%04i.txt' % x, cursor) if not os.path.exists(path)))
first = next(it, None)

if first:
    print(first)
```

**Output**

```
myfile0000.txt
```