# Making a for loop go until a certain condition becomes untrue

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I want to jump back to a certain point in my list of integers in python, so that a for loop keeps going longer.

I made that work by making a for loop go for a really long time, and simply include a break if my requirements are met. What would be a better way to achieve this?

```
t=0

i=0

for r in range(0,i):

    print(r)

    if par_y(t)>=0:

        i=+1

print(par_y(t))

t=+0.25

#or:

l=list(range(0,1)

t=0

for r in l:

    print(r)

    if par_y(t)>=0:

        [l]=0    

    print(par_y(t))  

    t=+0.25
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a [while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/743186/6144626): `while (a < 5): print('a); a += 1`? :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you are looking for is

```
while(condition == False):

    ##your code here
```