# does do while loop exist in python?

Tags: python

Recently came to be in need of `do while` loop in python, but couldn't find the syntax for it or does it even exist?

I tried below, but am getting syntax errors:

```
do{
    #c0d3 h3r3
} while(1=1)
```

or:

```
do:
    #c0d3 h3r3
while (1=1)
```

Can anyone tell me the syntax for it or tell me if it don't exist in python?
I am in python3 django.

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/743186/4980722

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have do-while loop, and you are assigning a value in your loop not comparing