# How do I iterate at the end rather than at the beginning of a loop in python without do while?

Tags: python, do-while

Forgive me, I am new to python.

In other languages, When I want to iterate at the end of a loop, rather than at the beginning I'd use a `do while` loop.

Python doesn't have a `do while` so I have done this:

```
iter_ = zip(x_list, y_list)
x,y = initial_values()
while x:
    foo(x,y)
    x,y = next(iter_,(False,False))
```

This works fine, but I am not fully satisfied with:

- the default `(False,False)` tuple. However I find it preferable
  to `try except: StopIteration; break`
- the use of x as the condition, as x could be an element which would legitimately be interpreted as `False` in a logical test. However I find it preferable to introducing a separate condition variable and test in addition to the `next()` call

What is the best/most python idiomatic way to perform iteration at the end rather than the beginning of the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python)

Comment: @OlvinRoght. I looked at that thank you. The answer I thought was best there was condition = True; while condition:condition = test_loop_condition() which is similar to my while x: x = next(iter,False). However my question has the additional aspect of wishing to iterate at the end rather than at the beginning of the loop. I have simplified the question to make that clearer

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
z = set_z_for_first_pass()  
for x,y in zip(x_list,y_list):
   if not x: break
   foo(x,y,z)
   z = set_z_for_subsequent_passes()
```

Comment: Is the `if not x:break` needed / doing anything? I don't thing the test will ever be True other than in the edge case that an element in x_list evaluates to False, and in that case, testing for False to terminate the iteration is not what you'd want.

Comment: Well, your original code suggested that (`while x:`); you can safely drop it.

Comment: Yes, but in my code the `while x` is testing if the iteration is finished. Hence it is needed there. In the loop you suggest that test is being performed in the `for` statement. So yes, we agree that the `if not x: break` above should be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different ways of answering your question.

First, concerning the problem-solving only, I would say that your use case for using a `do...while` loop is artificial, and maybe comes from some other language that uses this kind of convoluted thinking. In Python, I would use:

```
z = calc_z_for_first_pass()
for x,y in zip(x_list, y_list) 
    foo(x,y,z)
    z = calc_z_for_subsequent_passes()
```

Second, there are indeed cases in which you would like to have a `do...while` loop, for example something like:

```
do:
    z = calc_z()
while not is_valid(z)
```

In that case, you need to manually emulate your own `do...while` loop (see [[Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python]) as suggested by Olvin):

```
while True:
    z = calc_z()
    if is_valid(z):
        break
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid both `break` and `try: except` but I am starting to lean towards `iter_ = zip(x_list, y_list; while True: do_stuff(); try: x,y = next(iter_); except StopIteration:break`. Adding the try: else: block would also allow iteration to take place at the exact desired point in the loop. Perhaps that's the best way