# Python go to input function every time another function ends

Tags: python

```
import json


user_input = input("**^**: ").lower()

#d
if (user_input == "learn"):
    backslash = "\\"
    phrase = input("What phrase do you want me to reply to: ")
    answer = input("What do you want me to answer: ")

    #Checks for illegal signs
    if backslash in phrase and backslash in answer:
        print ("Contains illegal signs")
    else:
        print("I leant something new")
        data = {}
        data[phrase] = []
        data[phrase].append({
            'phrase': phrase,
            'answer': answer
        })
        with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
```

that is my script that put the user input into a file to later use. My problem is i dont know how to make it go back to `user_input = input("**^**: ").lower()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulate a do-while loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code in a while loop to keep it going.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("**^**: ").lower()
    
    if(user_input == "learn"):
        # ...
```

the while True condition will keep it running until you close the program.

Comment: lol thanks i had a brainfreeze but the simplest is the best in some cases