# When I introduce a variable that I will define later, do I set it equal to 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am a new programmer in the Python language. I was having trouble defining the variable user_guess because I was planning on defining it later in my program when the user inputs their answer. I later found the correct answer which is what the code below represents. My question is: If I introduce my variable, but plan on defining it later in my program, do I set it equal to 0?

```
user_guess = 0
magic_number = 5

while user_guess != magic_number:
    print("What is the magic number?")
    user_guess = int(input())

print("You have correctly guessed the magic number!")
```

Comment: `None` or `not magic_number` are both good values here =)

Comment: Picking a tiny nit here: `input()` can take a prompt as an argument, so you don't need a separate `print(...)` before it.

Comment: Excellent question generally, in this specific example there are other approaches to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/emulate-a-do-while-loop-in-python  for reference

Answer (score 3):

```
user_guess = None
```

`None` is the value in Python that signifies a lack of a meaningful value. It's the best value to use when you must define a variable but have no real value to assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how that variable is used later. In your case, you only define it early so that the `while` loop runs at least once. It could be anything except `5`. `0` is okay but `user_guess = None` to hint that it needs to be filled in would be common.

If the variable has a reasonable default and is only changed sometimes, use that.

```
meaning_of_life = 42
if os.path.exists('meaning.txt'):
    meaning_of_life = int(open('meaning.txt').readline())
```

And if the variable is set unilterally, don't include a default

```
meaning_of_life = int(input("Give meaning: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

user_guess = []
magic_number = random.randint(1,10)

while user_guess != magic_number:
    print("What is the magic number?")
    user_guess = int(input())
print("You have correctly guessed the magic number! was " + str(magic_number) + " and you guessed it in " + str(user_guess) + " tries!")
```

```
You could also clear it with [] which sets it to nothing. You can set a random number with random.randint and shows how many tries you have taken to get the correct number!
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I really appreciate the help!