# Repeat a process until a condition is reached

Tags: python

I need to create a program in which it allows the user to choose the quantity of perfect combinations that they want to see. A combination is perfect when the number is multiple of 3 and 5. For example if I have input 5 the program will need to start from 0 and once it reaches the number that is perfect shows a "perfect" each time it is perfect

I have been trying to use:

```
combi = (int(input())
count = 0

for i in range(combi):
      if (i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0):
          print("Perfect")
```

I do not know how to make it count since 0 until we have 5 numbers which are perfect

Comment: Sounds like **fizzbuzz**. You should probably Google it.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/how-to-emulate-a-do-while-loop) question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break` statement:

```
combi = (int(input())
count = 0

for i in range(combi):
      if (i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0):
          print("Perfect")
          count += 1
      if count == 5:
          break
```