# How to while loop that only run when certain condition is met

Tags: python

I want a while loop that only run when certain condition is met. For example, I need to loop  the condition A `if listposts != 0 and listposts != listView:` to check whether there is a new record or not. If it found a new record it will do function `B` and stop until the condition is met again.

I'm new to programming and I tried with this code but its still looping endlessly.

```
while True:

    if listposts != 0 and listposts != listView:
        Condition = True
         while Condition == True :
                      function B()
                
                      Condition = False
```

What I want to achieve is the loop will stop after 1 loop and wait until the condition is met to loop again.

Comment: `while <condition>`. If you're looking for a do-while loop, check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/how-to-emulate-a-do-while-loop).

Comment: Your code seems to do what you want according to the vague description. Please provide a [mre] of what you want to achieve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to emulate a do-while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/how-to-emulate-a-do-while-loop)

Comment: @Piero I'm not sure this answers the question (I'm not completely sure what the question ***is***) but anyway if you think this question is a duplicate then please don't answer it. If anything, you should answer in the duplicate ***target*** (after you've made sure your answer doesn't already exist)

Comment: What is `listposts`  and `listView` ?

Comment: Where do `new records` come from ? When is the loop supposed to stop ? A `while True:` loop will run endlessly, that's probably what you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

From what you expect as behavior you need 3 things:

1. a condition-test (as function) returning either `True` or `False`
2. a loop that calls the condition-test regularly
3. a conditional call of function `B()` when condition is met (or condition-test function returns `True`)

```py
# list_posts can change and is used as parameter
# listView is a global variable (could also be defined as parameter)
# returns either True or Fals
def condition_applies(list_posts):
    return list_posts != 0 and list_posts != listView
# Note: method names are by convention lower-case
def B():  
    print("B was called")

# don't wait ... just loop and test until when ?
# until running will become False
running = True
while running:
   if condition_applies(listposts):
       print("condition met, calling function B ..")
       B()
   # define an exit-condition to stop at some time
   running = True
```

Warning: This will be an endless-loop!
So you need at some point in time to set `running = False`.
Otherwise the loop will continue infinite and check if condition applies.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that you have a producer/consumer like situation.

IMHO your loop is ok. The principle applied here is called polling. Polling keeps looking for new items by constantly asking.

Another way of implementing this in a more CPU optimized way (using less CPU) requires synchronization. A synchronization object such as a mutex or semaphore will be signaled when a new element is available for processing. The processing thread can then be stopped (e.g. [WaitForSingleObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) on Windows), freeing the CPU for other things to do. When being signaled, Windows finds out that the thread should wake up and let's it run again.

[Queue.get() and Queue.put()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) are such methods that have synchronization built-in.

Unfortunately, I see many developers using Sleep() instead, which is not the right tool for the job.

Here's a producer/consumer example:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import random
import queue

q = queue.Queue(10)  # Shared resource to work on. Synchronizes itself
producer_stopped = False
consumer_stopped = False


def producer():
    while not producer_stopped:
        try:
            item = random.randint(1, 10)
            q.put(item, timeout=1.0)
            print(f'Producing {str(item)}. Size: {str(q.qsize())}')
        except queue.Full:
            print("Consumer is too slow. Consider using more consumers.")

def consumer():
    while not consumer_stopped:
        try:
            item = q.get(timeout=1.0)
            print(f'Consuming {str(item)}. Size: {str(q.qsize())}')
        except queue.Empty:
            if not consumer_stopped:
                print("Producer is too slow. Consider using more producers.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer_stopped = False
    p = Thread(target=producer)
    p.start()

    consumer_stopped = False
    c = Thread(target=consumer)
    c.start()

    sleep(2)  # run demo for 2 seconds. This is not for synchronization!

    producer_stopped = True
    p.join()
    consumer_stopped = True
    c.join()
```