# How do I convert this C# do-while loop into a Python while loop?

Tags: python, c#

This is the C# do-while loop *where, **r** is a BinaryReader*:

```
int data_len = 0, shift = 0;
byte b;
do
{
    b = r.ReadByte();
    data_len = data_len | ((b & 0x7F) << shift);
    shift += 7;
}
while ((b & 0x80) != 0);
```

This is what I came up with *it fails with large sizes, so it is wrong*

```
data_len = 1    # Because 1 byte is still required to store a zero
shift = 0
b = self.read_uint8()
while (b & 0x80) != 0:
    data_len |= (b & 0x7F) << shift
    shift += 7
    b = self.read_uint8()
return data_len
```

as well as this:

```
b = self.read_uint8()
data_len = b & 0x7F
shift = 0
    while (b & 0x80) != 0:
    b = self.read_uint8()
    data_len |= (b & 0x7F) << shift
    shift += 7
return data_len
```

Both do not work.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data to show what's not working?

Comment: A simple way to emulate a do-while loop with a while loop is to unroll the first iteration. You almost succeeded to do this in the second snipped, but you incorrectly initalized shift to 0 (it needs to be 7 after the first, unrolled loop)

Comment: Check out the answer here for how to emulate a do while loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743164/how-to-emulate-a-do-while-loop

Comment: @Lesiak I will try that thanks.

Comment: @timegb I am parsing FLP file events, its basically a varint algorithm going on