# Creating the war(card) game using OOP in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, while-loop

I am trying to create the war card game where 2 players draw a card each on the table, and the player whose card has max value gets both the cards, if the card values are equal(called war condition) each player draws 5 cards, and the value of the last card among these 5 cards are compared and works similarly as above. A player wins when either the other player runs out of cards or if in war condition the other player has less than 5 cards.

My questions:

1. When I am running the game logic sometimes it runs but sometimes it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Why?
2. I can notice that when the total number of cards for both players at all times should be 52, but here it is decreasing. Why? (I can see that the cards are getting lost every time the game goes into war condition, but I am not able to understand why that is happening, since I am adding all the 10 cards to the player whose card has a greater value.)

I have tried another method where I assume that players are always at war and then approach it, which works. But I want to understand why, if I break it into steps which I am trying to do here, is it not working?

Code:

```
import random

suits = ['Hearts','Clubs','Spades','Diamonds']

ranks = ['Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']

values = {'Two': 2, 'Three': 3, 'Four': 4, 'Five': 5, 'Six' : 6 , 'Seven' :7, 'Eight': 8,'Nine':9,
          'Ten':10,'Jack':11, 'Queen': 12,'King': 13,'Ace':14 }
```

classes:

```
class Card():  
    
    
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = values[rank]
    
    #string method
    def __str__(self):
        
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit 

class Deck():

  def __init__(self):

    self.all_cards = []  #list of objects

    for suit in suits:

      for rank in ranks:
        #create card object

        created_card = Card(suit,rank)

        self.all_cards.append(created_card)


  def shuffle(self):   #method to shuffle the card

    random.shuffle(self.all_cards)



  def deal_one(self):

    return self.all_cards.pop()  #we want the last card from deck


class Player():

  def __init__(self,name):

    self.name  = name
    self.all_cards = []

  def remove_one(self):

    return self.all_cards.pop(0)    #to remove card from beginning of the list

    

  def add_cards(self,new_cards):


    if type(new_cards) == type([]):

      self.all_cards.extend(new_cards)

    else:

      self.all_cards.append(new_cards)

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Player {self.name} has {len(self.all_cards)} cards.'
```

And below is the final game logic:

```
#create 2 new instances of the player class

player1_name = input('Enter the name of Player1: ')

player2_name = input('Enter the name of Player2: ')

player1 = Player(player1_name)
player2 = Player(player2_name)
newdeck = Deck()
newdeck.shuffle()

#splitting the deck among the two players - alternate card from deck goes to each player respectively

for i in range(0,len(newdeck.all_cards)-1,2):  

  player1.add_cards(newdeck.all_cards[i])
  player2.add_cards(newdeck.all_cards[i+1])

#for x in range(26):

 # player1.add_cards(newdeck.deal_one())
  #player2.add_cards(newdeck.deal_one())

print(player1)
print(player2)


game_status = True
    
round_num = 0
while game_status == True:

  round_num +=1
  print(f"Round {round_num}")


  if len(player1.all_cards) == 0:

    print('Player 1 out of cards'+ player2.name + 'Wins!')
    game_status = False
    break
  
  if len(player2.all_cards) == 0:

    print('Player 2 out of cards' + player1.name + 'Wins!')
    game_status = False
    break


  else:

     
    player_cards = []
    player1_card = player1.remove_one()
    player2_card = player2.remove_one()
    player_cards.append(player1_card)
    player_cards.append(player2_card)
    
    

    print('player1_card_value: ',player1_card.value)
    print('')
    print('player2_card_value: ',player2_card.value)
    print('')
    print(player1)
    print('')
    print(player2)


    at_war = True

    

    if player1_card.value == player2_card.value:  

      while at_war == True:


        player1_list = []
        player2_list = []

        card_list = []


        if len(player1.all_cards) < 5:
            
          print('Player 2 won')

          game_status = False
          at_war = False
          
          break

        elif len(player2.all_cards) <5:

          print('Player 1 won')
          game_status = False
          at_war = False
          break

        if len(player1.all_cards) >= 5 and len(player2.all_cards) >= 5:

          for i in range(5):
            player1_list.append(player1.remove_one())
            player2_list.append(player2.remove_one())


          card_list.extend(player1_list)
          card_list.extend(player2_list)

          print("CARD LIST LEN", len(card_list))

          if player1_list[0].value > player2_list[0].value:

            player1.add_cards(card_list)
            at_war = False
            break


          elif player1_list[0].value < player2_list[0].value:

            player2.add_cards(card_list)
          #player2.add_cards(player1_list)
            at_war = False
            break

          else:

            at_war = True

      


    elif player1_card.value > player2_card.value:

      player1.add_cards(player_cards)
      #player1.add_cards(player2_cards)

      #print('p1>p2', player1)

    elif player2_card.value > player1_card.value:

      player2.add_cards(player_cards)
      

    
          
        
            

     
print(player1)
print(player2)

if len(player1.all_cards) == 0:
  print('Player 2 won')

elif len(player2.all_cards) == 0:
  print('Player 1 won')
```

Output: When it was stuck in an infinite loop:(You can see the total number of cards is now 34 instead of 52.)
[image]

Comment: I'd say in the future, avoid asking questions like this because it's so broad and you're basically asking someone to debug your code. But I also built a card game in python so I find it interesting. A good way to debug is print out the number of cards after every method and just see for yourself EXACTLY where you're losing your cards. Also it really helps me personally to put simple comments anywhere it makes sense, e.g. above if statements, just to avoid confusion. Similarly for the infinite loop, just try to pinpoint the exact moment things go wrong.

Comment: @MichealSkarn thanks for your suggestions I will keep them in mind. I forgot to mention but I can see that the cards are getting lost every time the game goes into war condition. But I am not able to understand why that is happening since I am adding the 10 cards to the player whose card has greater value.

Comment: Oh okay I gotcha. Also I think your problem may be that `break` doesn't exit all loops, only the immediate one. Hence, when one player has less than five cards, you skip past the second loop back to the first while loop (without giving either player 10 cards which is why you're losing cards) and then go right back into the second loop in an infinite pattern. I'm not positive but I would bet this is your issue. You can fix it in many ways, but something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357255/python-exit-out-of-two-loops would work.