# Naming Loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, label, break

I recently read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java/886979#886979) which had a solution about labeling loops in Java.

I am wondering if such a loop-naming system exists in Python. I have been in a situation multiple times where I do need to break out of an outer `for` loop from an inner `for` loop. Usually, I solve this problem by putting the inner loop in a function that returns (among others) a boolean which is used as a breaking condition. But labeling loops for breaking seems a lot simpler and I would like to try that, if such functionality exists in python.

Does anyone know if it does?

Comment: Check the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops), hopefully it helps some. But from what I can see, no such system exists.

Comment: "But labeling loops for breaking seems a lot simpler "?  Simpler than proper functions?  How so?  Can you provide some evidence of how this would be "simpler"?

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but it would be a situation where I would have to create a function which will be used only in that one spot. Perhaps "simpler" was the wrong word. What I meant was that I wouldn't have to define a new function just for use in that ONE spot.

Comment: What's wrong with nested function definitions?  Also, what about redesigning the inner loop to avoid the `break`?

Comment: I just don't like them. I guess it's a personal preference

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was a proposal to include named loops in python [PEP3136](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/), however, it was rejected with an explanation [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html).  The rejection was mostly due to the rare number of circumstances where code readability would be improved by including this construct.

Comment: Labeled loops are often used as an alternative to `goto` in other languages. Python doesn't have `goto`, but there are [several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438844/is-there-a-label-goto-in-python).

Answer (score 21):

Here's a way to break out of multiple, nested blocks using a context manager:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def escapable():
    class Escape(RuntimeError): pass
    class Unblock(object):
        def escape(self):
            raise Escape()

    try:
        yield Unblock()
    except Escape:
        pass
```

You can use it to break out of multiple loops:

```
with escapable() as a:
    for i in xrange(30):
        for j in xrange(30):
            if i * j > 6:
                a.escape()
```

And you can even nest them:

```
with escapable() as a:
    for i in xrange(30):
        with escapable() as b:
            for j in xrange(30):
                if i * j == 12:
                    b.escape()  # Break partway out
                if i * j == 40:
                    a.escape()  # Break all the way out
```

Comment: yeah, that is extremely more readable than simply doing a loop with; `break 2` (php) or `continue loop1;` (javascript).. also, how pythonic is this indent hell spaghetti code really? Using `raise StopIteration` seems to be the cleanest, most readable, pythonic solution

Answer (score 15):

Though there are reasons to include named looped in language construct you can easily avoid it in python without loss of readability.
An implementation of the referred example  in python

```
>>> try:
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        for j in xrange(0,6):
            if i*j > 6:
                print "Breaking"
                raise StopIteration
            print i," ",j
except StopIteration:
    print "Done"


0   0
0   1
0   2
0   3
0   4
0   5
1   0
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   0
2   1
2   2
2   3
Breaking
Done
>>>
```

> I solve this problem by putting the inner loop in a function that
>   returns (among others) a boolean which is used as a breaking
>   condition.

I think you should try this. This is very pythonic, simple and readable.

Comment: +1. Using exceptions for flow control is perfectly cromulent in Python, though it is considered bad style in other languages, usually for performance reasons.

Comment: What if I just want to "continue" the outer loop, rather than stopping it?

Comment: @Guillochon Just put the try statement inside the first for loop

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Depending on what you are doing, there is good chance you can use something from itertools to flatten your nested for loops into a single for loop.