# looping back to a certain point in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am making a game in python 3.3 and am using while True: and break to make a loop this is 
        while True:
            print ("")
            print ("You must answer all questions in block capitals")
            print ("Welcome to maze runner")
            print ("To learn about the controls press C")
            print ("To learn the about the different types T")
            print ("To play press START")
            run = input ()
            #controls
            while True:
                if run == "C":
                    print ("To walk forward press W")
                    print ("To turn left press A")
                    print ("To turn right press D")
                    print ("To turn around press S")
                    print ("To block press B")
                    print ("To open pack press E")
                    print ("To open stats Press Q")
                    print ("To go back to the main menu press M")
                    return_to_main_menu = input ()
                    if return_to_main_menu != "M":
                       break
                else:
                   break

Is there a way to get the break after else to go back to the second while true and also to get the break after the if to go back to the first while true

Comment: possible duplicate of [Naming Loops in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419796/naming-loops-in-python)

Comment: This is a common problem. I've found (and marked as duplicate) the equivalent Python question. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Either combine boolean flags and breaks or wrap loop in try: except: ... and raise an exception instead of loop. Second option probably is not that efficient but can be simpler and more reliable then tinkering with boolean flags.

Answer (score 0):

Not like you do it.

Restructure your code so that everything in the inner loop is in a function.

Comment: How do I do something like this

Comment: Read the duplicate question for the answer.