# Python - `break` out of all loops

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, for-loop, break

I am using multiple nested `for` loops. In the last loop there is an `if` statement. When evaluated to `True` all the `for` loops should stop, but that does not happen. It only `break`s out of the innermost `for` loop, and than it keeps on going. I need all loops to come to a stop if the `break` statement is encountered.

My code:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    for i2 in range(i, 1001):
        for i3 in range(i2, 1001):
            if i*i + i2*i2 == i3*i3 and i + i2 + i3 == 1000:
                print i*i2*i3
                break
```

Comment: Rejected PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/

Comment: @mhlester what do you mean by rejected pep?

Comment: There was a proposal to **name** loops so you could break out of a specific one. It was rejected. The link has that discussion.

Comment: [Related post on naming loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8419796/198633)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You should put your loops inside a function and then return:

```
def myfunc():
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        for i2 in range(i, 1001):
            for i3 in range(i2, 1001):
                if i*i + i2*i2 == i3*i3 and i + i2 + i3 == 1000:
                    print i*i2*i3
                    return # Exit the function (and stop all of the loops)
myfunc() # Call the function
```

Using [`return`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/return.html) immediately exits the enclosing function.  In the process, all of the loops will be stopped.

Answer (score 24):

You can raise an exception

```
try:
    for a in range(5):
        for b in range(5):
            if a==b==3:
                raise StopIteration
            print b
except StopIteration: pass
```

Comment: Seems a bit odd to use an exception in this particular case (and doesn't look so nice), since the code should really be put into its own function - and `return` will then work.

Comment: In some cases one would still have to execute some lines of code after the loops, so I will go for the try except solution

Comment: Underrated answer. Perfect

Answer (score 11):

why not use a generator expression:

```
def my_iterator()
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        for i2 in range(i, 1001):
            for i3 in range(i2, 1001):
                yield i,i2,i3

for i,i2,i3 in my_iterator():
    if i*i + i2*i2 == i3*i3 and i + i2 + i3 == 1000:
        print i*i2*i3
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this the cleanest way possible to do it but you could do a bool check at the top of every loop.

```
do_loop = True

for i in range(1, 1001):
    if not do_loop:
        break
    for i2 in range(i, 1001):
        # [Loop code here]
        # set do_loop to False to break parent loops
```

Comment: I want to avoid adding more checks and loops. The current code is quite inefficient as it is.