# Move to next item in for loop from nested while loops PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, break

Hello I'm new at python and want to find good solution for I think easy problem. 
I have main for loop and inside it I have some (about 5) while loops. In some cases I need to move to next for loop item. There is a way to do that without putting a lot of breaks  ?

Code looks like :

```
for x in list:
    #Do some stuff
    {...}
    while loop:
        #do some stuff
        {...}
        while loop:
            #do some stuff
            {...}
            while loop:
                #do some stuff
                {...}
                while loop:
                    #do some stuff
                    if:
                        #here move to next item in for loop
                    else:
                        #other operations
```

Comment: Try to think about your code and see if you can avoid having so many nested loops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wrote that in for loop here is just one for loop

Comment: Yup, I realised and removed that part.

Comment: Possible answer here: [Naming loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419796/naming-loops-in-python)