# combine infinite with finite iterator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have two nested loops, the outer one using an infinite generator, and the inner a finite iterator (a list of numbers):

```
for j in itertools.count():
   for q in Q:
       ...
```

Under a given condition, I need to `break` out of both loops, which makes the code inelegant (I have to set a flag to trigger the second `break`). To avoid that, I thought I'd combine the two loops into one using

```
for j, q in itertools.product(itertools.count(), Q):
    ...
```

But when I did that, my computer got slower and slower, apparently swapping memory, until I had to kill the Python process.

The documentation of `product` says

> the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory

so I assumed the result of `product` to be a generator, which creates elements of the product on demand. But the slowing down and swapping speaks against that.

What did I wrong? How can I achieve what I wanted, a single loop combining an infinite generator with a list?

Comment: Can you put the code in a function so that instead of having to set a flag to break out of two levels of loop, you simply return from the function?

Comment: @alaniwi I could, but it would be really unnatural. These two loops are part of a larger algorithm that doesn't decompose into separate parts; lots of shared state.

Comment: Fair enough. Pity that python has no equivalent of perl's named loops - https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html

Comment: There is a very interesting solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419796/naming-loops-in-python involving raising `StopIteration` and catching it at the level that you want. (I guess that any exception will do, but in terms of readability, it is the obvious one to use.)

Comment: @alaniwi, it is interesting, thanks! But Iains solution works well for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generator using a comprehension. Comprehensions support iterating over multiple iterables at once using multiple `for`s

```
for j, q in ((j, q) for j in itertools.count() for q in Q):
    ...
```

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what performance penalty would that be?

Comment: Works great, thanks! I still wonder why `product` doesn't do the equivalent though.

Comment: @IainShelvington: Mostly the expense of suspending and resuming the generator over and over. Packing and unpacking tuples also has a cost, as does fiddling with `j` on iterations where you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Your documentation quote comes from [the following context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, except that
> the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in
> memory:
>
> ```
> def product(*args, repeat=1):
>     # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
>     # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
>     pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
>     result = [[]]
>     for pool in pools:
>         result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
>     for prod in result:
>         yield tuple(prod)
> ```

The intermediate results are all the `result` lists. The actual `itertools.product` implementation doesn't need to build those. It does, however, build something analogous to `pools`.

`itertools.product` needs to be able to iterate over its inputs repeatedly, so it materializes all inputs into tuples. This requirement doesn't apply to the first input when `repeat` is `1`, but the implementation materializes all inputs anyway, perhaps for consistency or ease of implementation. `itertools.count()` cannot be fully materialized, hence the results you saw.

One option you have is a generator expression. The following loop:

```
for j, q in ((j, q) for j in itertools.count() for q in Q):
```

will behave like you wanted `itertools.product` to behave, though it will be slower than plain nested loops (because of the overhead of the generator). The performance penalty is just a constant factor, and it doesn't slow down the loop body, so it's rarely a problem.

If you can factor out the nested loops into a function, you can also use `return` instead of `break`:

```
def helper_function(stuff):
    for j in itertools.count():
        for q in Q:
            ...
            if whatever:
                return
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding in case it is useful to anyone, and based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420092/13596037, exceptions can be used to break or continue an outer loop, for example:

```
class ContinueOuter(Exception): pass
class BreakOuter(Exception): pass

try:
    for i in range(10):  # loop we want to break or continue from
        try:
            for j in range(3):
                print(i, j)
                if (i, j) == (3, 1):
                    raise ContinueOuter
                elif (i, j) == (4, 0):
                    raise BreakOuter
        except ContinueOuter:
            pass
except BreakOuter:
    pass
```