# How to break out of a nested while loop

Tags: python, nested-loops, break

I am having trouble breaking out of while loops. Here is my code

```
while (True):
    if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):
        ticker = 0
        while stack:
            x, y = stack.pop()
            mask[x, y] = True
            for dx, dy in neighbors:
                nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
                print ticker
                if (0 <= nx < dem_arr.shape[0] and 0 <= ny < dem_arr.shape[1] and dem_arr[x, y] > -100 and dem_arr[nx, ny] > -100 and not mask[nx, ny] and abs(dem_arr[nx, ny] - dem_arr[x, y]) <= 1):    #set elevation differnce
                    stack.append((nx, ny))  #if point is selected (true) array position gets added to stack and process runs over again
                    if ((nx, ny) not in counterStack):
                        counterStack.append((nx, ny)) 
                        dem_copy[(nx, ny)] = 8888
                        if (ticker >= 121):
                            print 'ticker ticked'
                            #if in this for loop need to break out of while stack:
                        else:
                            ticker += 1
    else:   
        print '!!!Point chosen has no data!!!'
        randx = random.randint(0, row-1)    #array begins at position 0,0
        randy = random.randint(0, col-1)
        continue
```

What I need to happen is `if (ticker >= 121):`is entered I need to break out of the `while stack:`and `while(True).`Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Use functions and `return`. It's better coding style than going so deep.

Comment: You can also raise an exception.

Comment: Couldn't you change while(True) to while(ticker < 121)? I'm guessing while(true) is just an infinite loop, never used it before though so I'm not sure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified example illustrating the concept of using functions to control the inner loop:

```
stack = range(1, 500)

def stack_loop():

    ticker = 0

    while stack:
        x = stack.pop()
        # Your implementation here
        if ticker >= 121:
            print("Ticker ticked")
            return True
        else:
            print("Ticker increased")
            ticker += 1

    return False

while True:
    if stack_loop():
        break
```

Move the inner loop's logic to an external function and use the `return` statement to control if you have to break out of the main loop or not.

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**: You could also move the entire block to the function and simply `return` from it:

```
stack = range(1, 500)

def main_loop():

    while True:
        ticker = 0
        while stack:
            x = stack.pop()
            # Your implementation here
            if ticker >= 121:
                print("Ticker ticked")
                return
            else:
                print("Ticker increased")
                ticker += 1

main_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a variable to keep track (`breakout` in this case):

```
while (True):
    if (dem_arr[randx, randy] > -100):
        ticker = 0
        breakout = False
        while stack and not breakout:
            x, y = stack.pop()
            mask[x, y] = True
            for dx, dy in neighbors:
                nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
                print ticker
                if (0 <= nx < dem_arr.shape[0] and 0 <= ny < dem_arr.shape[1] and dem_arr[x, y] > -100 and dem_arr[nx, ny] > -100 and not mask[nx, ny] and abs(dem_arr[nx, ny] - dem_arr[x, y]) <= 1):    #set elevation differnce
                    stack.append((nx, ny))  #if point is selected (true) array position gets added to stack and process runs over again
                    if ((nx, ny) not in counterStack):
                        counterStack.append((nx, ny)) 
                        dem_copy[(nx, ny)] = 8888
                        if (ticker >= 121):
                            print 'ticker ticked'
                            #if in this for loop need to break out of while stack:
                            breakout = True
                            break
                        else:
                            ticker += 1
    else:   
        print '!!!Point chosen has no data!!!'
        randx = random.randint(0, row-1)    #array begins at position 0,0
        randy = random.randint(0, col-1)
        continue
```

Comment: See the answer from [Markus Jarderot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the comments already made. In addition, think about the while loop. While True: is inherently an infinite loop. You could return to the caller from within a function, you could break in the same level as the loop, or you could replace True with an expression that starts False and becomes True under the appropriate condition.

edit:
You aren't programming in Java or C anymore. No need to put parentheses around "True". :) - Or the other conditionals.