# How to end loop one iteration earlier?

Tags: python, iteration, neural-network, nested-loops

I often need to end loop one iteration earlier, how do I do it elegantly?
[Breaking out of nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops) looks messy to me.
For now I workaround it with return, but when later on I want to make a class, having return in the middle of constructor looses sense.

```
def forward(neurons):
for layerId, layer in enumerate(neurons):
    if layerId == neurons.__len__() - 1:
        return
    for idx, i in enumerate(neurons[layerId]):
        for idx2, n in enumerate(neurons[layerId+1]):
            neurons[layerId+1][idx2] += i * sigmoid(weights[layerId][idx][idx2])
```

Comment: *having return in the middle of constructor looses sense* You could still use a function and call it from the contructor.

Comment: Note that you should use `len(neurons)` rather than `neurons.__len__()`. What's the problem with `break`?

Comment: Your example is not a case of breaking out of nested loops. At the point you seem to be wishing to break from the loops are not nested (yet). Then what's the problem with using `break`?

Comment: Sorry; my mistake; break applied on lowest depth works ok.
I don't delete question though, since i generally want to know how to get out of nested loop with enumerate earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One generic solution would be to create a generator from the iterator (that will yield all but the last element the iterator yields):

```
def but_last(p):
    first = True
    for x in p:
        if not first:
            yield last
        first = False
        last = x

for layerId, layer in but_last(enumerate(neurons)):
    do_your_stuff(layerId, layer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `break`:

```
for i in range(1,100):
  if i==10:
    break
```

That will kill the loop as soon as a condition is matched.

Comment: But surely you can just apply this condition on the `if layerId == neurons.__len__() -1` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to implement your neurons object as a class with method `__iter__` to make the object iterable according to the behavior you like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 2
        yield 5
        yield 10


obj = MyClass()

for i in obj:
    print i
```