# Loop in Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am wondering if you can restart, in python, Loop A while you are in Loop B. For example:

```
while True:     #Loop A
    while True:      #Loop B
        ans = int("Question")
        if ans == "y":
            print("Something")
        else:
            ???
```

With ??? representing the code to go back and repeat Loop A.
Please, I really need this answer. For those of you who have or will answer, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `break`?

Comment: Why not just `break`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops - the question itself is answered by `break`, but if there was other logic involved "go repeat A" is not the same thing as "stop current loop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you can use `break` to exit the loop you are in.

```
while True:     #Loop A
   while True:      #Loop B
       ans = int("Question")
       if ans == "y":
           print("Something")
       else:
           break
```

Comment: Thank you so much!