# How to iterate list python

Tags: python

i have a file like this:

```
{"user1": {"Login": "Bob", "Secret": "passkey1"}}
{"user2": {"Login": "John", "Secret": "passkey2"}}

with open('users') as data_file:    
   data = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]
```

How i can iterate on user1,2 etc to get they 'Secret'?
Users just an example

Comment: `[x[list(x.keys())[0]]["Secret"] for x in data]` btw show what you have tried so far next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
with open('users') as data_file:    
  for line in data_file:
      for k, v in json.loads(line).items():
          print(v['Secret'])
```

Output

```
passkey1
passkey2
```

This code will create for each line a dictionary and then you can extract the 'Secret' value from each one.

Comment: Thank you, this example is the best way for me

Comment: You welcome, Happy to help. It will be appreciated if you can mark the answer.

Comment: Can you explain one more thing? When i trying to iterate over the all passkeys i need to stop iterations when some condition is true. if v['Secret'] == variable: print OK else: BAD
But it prints one OK and one BAD in depend of passkey count

Comment: do an if statement like `if  v['Secret'] == 'passkey1':` and then you can use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: `if v['Secret'] == Token:
            Name = (v['Login'])
            print(Name) 
            bot.reply_to(message, 'Alloha, ' + Name)
            break
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, "I can't identify you') `

I receive both answers :(

Comment: Yes, That is because it's a nested loop in order to make it work you need also to break the outer loop this link may help you with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops

Comment: Oh, really. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('users.txt') as data_file:    
   data = [list(json.loads(line).values())[0]['Secret'] for line in data_file]
print(data)
```

```
['passkey1', 'passkey2']
```

This is what my file looked like

```
{"user1": {"Login": "Bob", "Secret": "passkey1"}}
{"user2": {"Login": "John", "Secret": "passkey2"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following:

```
import json

{"user1": {"Login": "Bob", "Secret": "passkey1"}}
{"user2": {"Login": "John", "Secret": "passkey2"}}

with open('users.txt') as data_file:    
    data = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]

for line in data:
    print(line.get(list(line.keys())[0]).get("Secret"))
```

This will work as long as the format of the dictionary is consistent, but what I mean you have one user per dictionary.