# Python - Breaking out of inner loop from nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop

'break' is used to break out of the nested loop.

```
main_keyword = ["11111", "22222", "333333", "44444", "55555"]

for pro in main_keyword:
    # 1
    for i in range(3):
        if pro == '333333':
            print(pro, "failure")
            break
        else:
            print(pro, "Pass")
            pass

    # 2
    for a in range(3):
        print(a)
```

However, the #1 for loop escapes, but the #2 for loop is executed.

```
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
0
1
2
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
0
1
2
333333 failure
0
1
2
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
0
1
2
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
0
1
2
```

What I want is if pro == '333333' , then proceed to the next operation of the top-level loop without working on both for loop #1 and #2.

```
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
0
1
2
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
0
1
2
333333 failure
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
0
1
2
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
0
1
2
```

I want the above result. help

Comment: are you looking for `continue`?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/654002/1138192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a multi-level `continue`.  But Python doesn't support multi-level `break` or `continue`.  However, you can achieve the equivalent effect by using a flag:

```
main_keyword = ["11111", "22222", "333333", "44444", "55555"]

for pro in main_keyword:
    # 1
    fail = False
    for i in range(3):
        if pro == '333333':
            print(pro, "failure")
            fail = True
            break
        else:
            print(pro, "Pass")
            pass

    if fail:
        continue

    # 2
    for a in range(3):
        print(a)
```

Comment: Perfectly resolved. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Set additional flag that skips exec on fail:

```
main_keyword = ["11111", "22222", "333333", "44444", "55555"]

for pro in main_keyword:
# 1
    failed = 0
    for i in range(3):
        if pro == '333333':
            print(pro, "failure")
            failed = 1
            break
        else:
            print(pro, "Pass")
            pass
    if failed: continue

# 2
    for a in range(3):
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it:

```
main_keyword = ["11111", "22222", "333333", "44444", "55555"]

for pro in main_keyword:
    # 1
    error = False
    for i in range(3):
        if pro == '333333':
            print(pro, "failure")
            error = True
            break
        print(pro, "Pass")

    # 2
    if not error:
        for a in range(3):
            print(a)
```

Result:

```
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
11111 Pass
0
1
2
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
22222 Pass
0
1
2
333333 failure
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
44444 Pass
0
1
2
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
55555 Pass
0
1
2
```