# how to stop iterating after the condition is done

Tags: python

I have

```
print(list_games)
array([[77, 63],
       [94, 49],
        [58, 98],
       ...,
       [ 7,  0],
       [68, 22],
       [ 1, 32]], dtype=int64)
```

I need to print the first pair and their index, which satisfy the condition, but my code print all pairs. How can I fix it?

```
for i in range(len(list_games)):
    for j in range(len(list_games)):
        if list_games[i][0] + list_games[j][1] == 131:
            print(list_games[i][0], list_games[j][1])
            break
```

And I get:

```
77 54
94 37
58 73
51 80
80 51
74 57
66 65
61 70
87 44
40 91
```

Comment: You might find these two other threads interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/189645 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/653509

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean to control if the first loop also should break or not.

```py
loop = True
for i in range(len(list_games)):
    for j in range(len(list_games)):
        if list_games[i][0] + list_games[j][1] == 131:
            print(list_games[i][0], list_games[j][1])
            loop = False
            break
    if loop == False:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to do it inside a function and `return` when the condition satisfies,

```
def match():
    for i in range(len(list_games)):
        for j in range(len(list_games)):
            if list_games[i][0] + list_games[j][1] == 131:
                return (list_games[i][0], list_games[j][1])

value = match()
print(value)
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: list_games = np.array([[77, 63], [94, 49], [58, 98],[ 7, 0], [68, 22], [ 1, 32]], dtype=np.int64)

In [2]: value = match()
   ...: print(value)
(68, 63)
```

Comment: This adds the overhead of an extra function call, in comparison to @behrouz 's answer