# How to break out of nested loops?

Tags: c, nested-loops, break

If I use a `break` statement, it will only break inner loop and I need to use some flag to break the outer loop. But if there are many nested loops, the code will not look good.

Is there any other way to break all of the loops? (Please don't use `goto stmt`.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
       if (condition) {
            // both of the loops need to break and control will go to stmt2
       }
   }    
}

stmt2
```

Comment: you may try int i and int j before the loop starts and then on the condition make them 1001 the loop will not iterate the next .

Comment: C++ version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257744/can-i-use-break-to-exit-multiple-nested-for-loops

Comment: I had a professor who's pet peeve was that you couldn't send a parameter to break, to indicate how many levels out you could go. If he had his way, the answer to your question would simply be 'break(2);', where '2' is the number of loops to break out of.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use:

```
if (condition) {
    i = j = 1000;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Works, but ugly and not general. What if someone changes the limit to 2000 (suppose the code is longer, so you don't immediately notice it)?

Comment: @ugoren It's also so simple then. what if you used a `const int count =1000 `, in the global Initialization. or as a `#define` macro.

Comment: As @ugoren points out, it's not a general solution. Since this is the first Google hit for this question, it would be nice if the general solution had been selected. Well people are used to checking out the #2 anyway.

Comment: I guess only need i=1000?

Answer (score 281):

No, don't spoil the fun with a `break`. This is the last remaining valid use of `goto` ;)

If not this then you could use flags to break out of deep nested loops.

Another approach to breaking out of a nested loop is to factor out both loops into a separate function, and return from that function when you want to exit.

Summarized - to break out of nested loops:

1. use `goto`
2. use flags
3. factor out loops into separate function calls

Couldn't resist including xkcd here :)

[image]

[source](http://xkcd.com/292/)

[Goto's are considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) but as many people in the comments suggest it need not be. If used judiciously it can be a great tool. Anything used in moderation is fun.

Comment: Goto is about as clear as you'll get here, yeah. Setting the exit variable to 1000 is even more kludgy.

Comment: I would like to add that gotos are not explicitly evil, they just can be used for evil. I find that there are quite a few cases, for example this, where they are the best solution. "Don't use gotos" is a good start, but I think the next step in skill allows you "Don't use long-range gotos".

Comment: although I like `goto`s for the WTF value, I strongly suggest going route 3 - applying it in all but the most trivial cases, it IMO gives the best results in the long run.

Comment: i love this comic. On a side note, `goto` is best if you know what you're doing and how to use it correctly. I use it all the time for breaking out of nested loops. Setting a flag solely for this purpose is ugly, and adds an extra compare instruction to every loop. Creating a function results in exponential amounts of add/subtracting the stack pointer.

Comment: I agree that there are cases where `goto` is the best answer (clearest, most efficient).  But as a general rule, it's best to use `goto` to break out of a statement, rather than to enter it.  Among other things, this will always result in a reducible flow graph (which should not impede optimization).  Try to avoid using `goto ` to enter a statement, such as a loop (which will generally result in an irreducible flow graph).

Comment: I would like to disagree with this: "Creating a function results in exponential amounts of add/subtracting the stack pointer". If there is a local (static) function which is called at only one point in the program flow, any half-decent compiler will inline it, and the resulting code is essentially the same as with goto. This possibly the easiest optimization case for any compiler.

Comment: Refactoring is usually the cleanest solution. However, if any outside-of-loop variables are changed during the inner loop, things get complicated. One possibility is to pass the variable to the inner function by reference (pointer), but this may confuse the compiler optimization and produce unnecessary extra code. Another possibility is to make such variables static at the module level, but that is not very beautiful, either. C is unfortunately missing nested functions, as they would solve this problem — unless you are willing to bind yourself to using gcc which provides an extension.

Comment: > Couldn't resist not including xkcd here :)
There is one "not" too many there. I hate to seem like (be) a nitpicker, but SO didn't allow me to correct it because the edit was too short.

Comment: I've been told god kills a kitten whenever someone uses a `goto`. But fear not, she'll probably settle for a small one since this is kind of a valid use.

Comment: @kmkaplan The link that your link links to is no longer working.

Comment: As @kmkaplan said, Donald E. Knuth's [Structured Programming with go to Statements](https://pic.plover.com/knuth-GOTO.pdf)  is an interesting article to balance Dijkstra's.

Answer (score 61):

One way is to put all the nested loops into a function and return from the inner most loop incase of a need to break out of all loops.

```
function() 
{    
  for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
   for(int j=0; j<1000;j++)
   {
      if (condition)
        return;
   }
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 51):

```
bool stop = false;
for (int i = 0; (i < 1000) && !stop; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; (j < 1000) && !stop; j++)
    {
        if (condition)
            stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution still increments both variables by one on _break_ which can cause trouble

Comment: One can set "stop = true;" and then "break;".  Then, right after the end of the inside "for" loop, do "if (stop) break;".

Comment: I think this is the most elegant non-`goto` solution. It doesn't require knowing the limits of `i` and `j` within the condition. I like the idea of putting `if (stop) break;` after the inner loop, which could itself `break` after setting `stop`.

Answer (score 32):

You'll need a boolean variable, if you want it readable:

```
bool broke = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
    if (condition) {
      broke = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (broke)
    break;
}
```

If you want it less readable you can join the boolean evaluation:

```
bool broke = false;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000 && !broke; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
    if (condition) {
      broke = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

As an ultimate way you can invalidate the initial loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
    if (condition) {
      i = size;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The last solution is the best for performance. Do not check additional booleans if further conditional branches can be avoided.

Answer (score 27):

I think `goto` will solve the problem

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        if (condition) {
            goto end;
        }
    }
}

end:
stmt2
```

Comment: @chikuba I got answer from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/goto.html and your answer is not posted when i am doing the same thing thats why i dont see your post

Answer (score 14):

Use this wise advice from LLVM team:

*"Turn Predicate Loops into Predicate Functions"*

See:

http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#turn-predicate-loops-into-predicate-functions

Answer (score 7):

Caution: This answer shows a truly obscure construction.

If you are using GCC, check out [this library](https://github.com/xbarin02/c-ext).
Like in PHP, `break` can accept the number of nested loops you want to exit.
You can write something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
       if(condition) {
            // break two nested enclosing loops
            break(2);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: And under the hood it is indeed [using `goto`](https://github.com/xbarin02/c-ext/blob/master/include/break#L35) :)

Comment: @iX3 I can use inline assembler and jmp instruction if that helps.

Comment: @DaBler, I didn't realize you were the author of that library. My comment was not meant as feedback but rather noting that this library uses the same method as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/how-to-break-out-of-nested-loops/47947714#answer-9695942). Hopefully your comment was meant as a joke because I think that using a language feature (even `goto`) is far preferably to inline asm (machine specific, easier to make a mistake, harder to read, ...).

Comment: @DaBler: the definition `#define do(cond)` is somewhat confusing: you should use `def` instead of `cond` to clarify that the macro argument is a definition, not a condition.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
       if(condition) {
            goto end;
   }
} 

end:
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need the values of i and j, this should work
but with less performance than others

```
for(i;i< 1000; i++){    
    for(j; j< 1000; j++){
        if(condition)
            break;
    }
    if(condition) //the same condition
        break;
}
```

Comment: Note that if the condition is dependent on `j` then the value of the condition needs to be stored in some way for this to still work.

Comment: You are right but after **break**, the value of **j** doesn't change and so is the value of the condition.

Comment: This is a broken solution and not valid in general. Either j isn't defined outside its loop or `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) { if (workComplete[i][j]) break; /* do work */ workComplete[i][j] = true; } if (workComplete[i][j]) break; ... }` is going to **always** break out of the outer loop after the first iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to refactor the code from two for loops into a for loop and one manual loop.  That way the break in the manual loop applies to the outer loop.  I used this once in a [Gauss-Jordan Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) which required three nested loops to process.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    int j = 0;

MANUAL_LOOP:;

    if (j < 1000)
    {
       if (condition)
       {
           break;
       }

       j++;
       goto MANUAL_LOOP;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to `goto`, why not just `goto` out of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I note that the question is simply, "Is there any other way to break all of the loops?" I don't see any qualification but that it not be `goto`, in particular the OP didn't ask for a *good* way. So, how about we `longjmp` out of the inner loop? :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int counter = 0;
  jmp_buf look_ma_no_goto;
  if (!setjmp(look_ma_no_goto)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        if (i == 500 && j == 500) {
          longjmp(look_ma_no_goto, 1);
        }
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("counter=%d\n", counter);
}
```

The `setjmp` function returns twice. The first time, it returns 0 and the program executes the nested for loops. Then when the both `i` and `j` are 500, it executes `longjmp`, which causes `setjmp` to return again with the value 1, skipping over the loop.

Not only will `longjmp` get you out of nested loops, it works with nested functions too!

Comment: Just when you think you know C...

Comment: `longjmp()` is **much worse** than `goto` for this purpose. Your example has undefined behavior because the value of `counter` after returning a second time from `setjmp()` could be `500500` as expected or `0` if `counter` happens to reside in a register saved and restored by `setjmp()`. To avoid this pitfall, you could qualify `counter` as `volatile`... DV for advocating a dreadful solution with only an implied caveat.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a flag, a rookie mistake is to exit a single loop, remember the double break, another practice that is not recommended but necessary in very high performance processes is to use goto and my favorite, a function with a return.

```
#include <iostream>

// Dont clone vars, use references, for performance
int calc(int &row, int &cols, int &max) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        sum += i + j;
        if (sum > max) {
          return sum;
        }
      }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int rows = 1000;
    int cols = 1000;
    int max = 1000;

    int result = calc(rows, cols, max);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternative version, a little more modular:

```
#include <iostream>

// Dont clone vars, use references, for performance
void calc(int &row, int &cols, int &max, int &result) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        sum += i + j;
        if (sum > max) {
          result = sum;
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    result = sum;
}

int main() {
    int rows = 1000;
    int cols = 1000;
    int max = 1000;

    int result = 0;
    calc(rows, cols, max, result);
    std::cout << "Result: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

GOTO example, completely discouraged today:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int rows = 1000;
    int cols = 1000;
    int max = 1000;

    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            result += i + j;
            if (result > max) {
                goto end;
            }
        }
    }

end:
    std::cout << "Result: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Break and boolean, nowadays they are discouraged in universities, you get worse performance than using goto because you have to check the break condition all the time although it is a more accepted method:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int rows = 1000;
    int cols = 1000;
    int max = 1000;

    int result = 0;
    bool done = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            result += i + j;
            if (result > max) {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (done) {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Result: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Conclusion: using a separate function has advantages in real life, in addition to the fact that you can parallelize them more easily (especially for processes where you must compare large amounts of bytes, this is advantageous).

Answer (score -3):

```
int i = 0, j= 0;

for(i;i< 1000; i++){    
    for(j; j< 1000; j++){
        if(condition){
            i = j = 1001;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Will break both the loops.

Comment: nice no logic break 1001

Answer (score -3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; i++) {
       if(condition) {
          func(para1, para2...);
          return;
       }
    }
}

func(para1, para2...) {
    stmt2;
}
```

Comment: So basically you're saying that it should (1) make a bunch of extra function calls and then (2) spin for the rest of the time when `condition` becomes false. Oh, and the second loop will run forever because it increments `i` instead of `j`, whoops...

Answer (score -4):

```
i = 0;

do
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) // by the way, your code uses i++ here!
  {
     if (condition)
     {
       break;
     }
  }

  ++i;

} while ((i < 1000) && !condition);
```