# look for only the first common element between two arrays

Tags: c, break, duplicates

I have two arrays, namely a[] and b[]. I would like to search if any element of a is present in b. Note that I do not want to find all duplicate occurrences, if any one element from a[] exists in b[], I would like to report it and break out without checking the rest of a[] or b[]

I'm a bit confused about how 'break' operates. Can 'break' break out of any kind of loop - for/while, but it breaks out of only the 'innermost loop' around where it's placed in code ?

This is my solution and please suggest if there is a better implementation for this O(n^2) approach

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
 int b[] = {11,2,3,7,8,9,6,10,11};
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 int duplicate = 0;

 for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<sizeof(b)/sizeof(int);j++)
  {
   if(a[i] == b[j])
   {
    printf("Duplicates found for [%d]\n",a[i]);
    duplicate = 1;
    break;
   }
  }

  if(duplicate == 1)
  {
   break;
  }
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you sort the arrays? Instead of `O(n^2)` you can make the search in `O(2.n.log n + n)` which is the same as `O(n.log n)`

Comment: If you sort each array with an O(nlogn) sort such as quick sort or merge sort, then you could go through the arrays in O(n) time, yielding overall complexity of O(nlogn).

Comment: And yes, `break` will break out of the nearest loop it finds, be it a `for` or a `while`

Comment: Also ... a bigger indentation does not hurt compiler performance or executable speed and really really helps the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

breaks generally break out of the most inner loop in c. You have used it correctly.

if u want to just report a duplicate, then u can put this code into a fuction and whenever a duplicate is found, you just return. The function would look like this:

```
//Here a and b are pointers to array 
//n1 and n2 are number of elements in array a,b
chk_dup(int *a,int *b,int n1,,int n2){

for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
  {
   if(a[i] == b[j])
   {
    printf("Duplicates found for [%d]\n",a[i]);
    //duplicate = 1;
    //break;
    return;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

You cannot use sizeof(a) here becoz its just a pointer to array.Same goes for sizeof(b).

You can make this algorithm more efficient by sorting the arrays using quicksort(that would take O(nlgn)) and then for each element in a do binary search in b.

pseudo code for that is something like this:

```
//Here a and b are pointers to sorted arrays 
//n1 and n2 are number of elements in array a,b
chk_dup(int *a,int *b,int n1,,int n2){

for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
 {
   //find a[i] in b using binary search.
   int found=binary_search(a[i],b);
   if(found){
     printf("Found Duplicate");
     return;
   }
 }
 printf("No duplicate found");
}
```

So, the whole algorithm works in O(nlgn). While the algorithm you are using can take O(n^2).

Otherwise your code is perfectly fine and the **use of break** is correct

Answer (score 3):

`break` only breaks the innermost loop in which it is used. If you want to avoid the ugly syntax then you have multiple solutions:

- ignore this optimization until you prove it's relevant
- move the code inside a function that accepts the two arrays as arguments so that you can directly `return` from the function without having to break.
- adjust indices `i` and `j` after that you found a duplicate to make both loops return gracefully
- use a `goto` instruction (which is not advisable in any case)

Other solutions, with complexity lower than O(n^2) could require some additional data structure, like a hashset or sorting of data.

Comment: I think refactoring the code to a function makes best sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `goto` as noted here [How to break out of nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/breaking-of-nested-loop) it's the last remaining valid use of this...

And maybe there is a better solution using xor, not sure if you can reduce the

complexity though...