# Stop reading when reading mutliple files (without goto)

Tags: c

I have files with a single column full of numbers and I want to sum all the files. The problem is to be able to exit as soon as invalid data is found (as soon as `fprintf` fails).

A first attempt using `goto` (and inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/how-to-break-out-of-nested-loops/9695942#9695942)) is the following

```
while(1) {
    sum_a = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++){
        if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1){
            goto end; // yeah, I know...
        }
        sum_a += a;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum_a); // Should NOT be read if anything failed before
}

end:
for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

I would glad to see a nicer solution (ie not using `goto` and `while(1)`!). I don't want to mess up with many flags set and unset in a dirty way.

Comment: This question is probably a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: int is_ok = 1; while(is_ok) { body; if(fail) is_ok = 0; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why?**

It's a perfectly valid use case of `goto`. It's the most readable solution, and does the job. Why bother changing it?

Comment: OK, so then no problem. I just want no raptor in my office ;)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you wish to avoid this perfectly legitimate use of `goto` as a learning exercise, here is how you can do it: make a flag variable that indicates loop termination, set it in the inner loop, and check it in all loops:

```
int stop = 0;
while(!stop) {
    sum_a = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++){
        if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1){
            stop = 1;
            break;
        }
        sum_a += a;
    }
    if (!stop) {
        printf("%d\n", sum_a);
    }
}
for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

Note how your code instantly became less readable, because `printf` needs to be protected by a conditional.

Another trick would be rewriting with a single loop and using `break` to stop. The readability would not suffer as much:

```
int i = 0;
for (;;) { // This "forever" loop is idiomatic in C
    if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1) {
        break;
    }
    sum_a += a;
    if (++i == N) {
        printf("%d\n", sum_a);
        i = 0;
    }
}
for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
int rc = 1;
do
{
    sum_a = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++){
        rc = fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a);
        if(rc == 1){
            sum_a += a;    
            printf("%d\n", sum_a);
        }        
    }
}while(rc == 1);

for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I modified the example

Comment: Now your code prints too much - once per iteration of the inner loop, while OP's prints once per iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is that I do not understand the need for two loops in this case.

Comment: OP reads `N` files until one of them runs out. At this point he stops all reading.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see it.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* look ugly (it is), but it is short and minimal:

```
sum_a = 0;
i =0;
while(1) {
        if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1) break;
        sum_a += a;
        if (++i < N) continue;
        printf("%d\n", sum_a);
        break;
        }

for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

---

Maybe a bit less ugly:

```
sum_a = 0;
for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++){
    if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1) break;
    sum_a += a;
    }

if (i == N) printf("%d\n", sum_a);

for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
    fclose(infiles[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need a big exit jump, I usually encapsulate the loops into a function and simply use `return`, e.g.:

```
void read(FILE*[] infiles, int N)
{
    for(;;) {
        sum_a = 0;
        for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++){
            if(fscanf(infiles[i], "%d\n", &a) != 1){
                return;
            }
            sum_a += a;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum_a);
    }
}

void cleanup(FILE*[] infiles, int N)
{
    for(i=0 ; i<N ;i++)
        fclose(infiles[i]);
}

read(infiles, N);
cleanup(infiles, N);
```

It usually also helps reading the code.