# while loop exit, without well-known way

Tags: c

I just asked a same question, but the question is closed, maybe I broke the rules...or mess.

anyway
i know about loop exit like break, while(bool), return, n=1, n=0 while(n),
I want another method other than the above one.

i solved this problem with while(mode!=2)
thanks for all, to answer my immature question :) i promise hard study by foundation your feedback!

question is closed.

here's my code structure :)       ↓

```
        
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main() {
    
    int  mode=1;
    while (mode != 2)
    {
        printf("\ninput: "); scanf("%d", &mode);
        switch (mode) 
        {
        case 1: printf("\none"); Sleep(1500); break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nsomething");
            Sleep(1500);
            break;

        default: printf("\nStackOverFlow");  break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a boolean state variable instead of a hard-coded infinite loop, is a common way to solve this problem. If it's used as part of the loop condition, or as a separate condition for a `break`, doesn't really matter and depends more on your use-case.

Comment: The problem you're running into is that a `break` at that point refers to the enclosing `switch` statement, not to the `while` loop that contains it. C has no multi-level `break`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What do you need that `break`, `return` and loop conditions lack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break out of nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695902/how-to-break-out-of-nested-loops)

Comment: Editing the code in the question after it has received answers/comments invalidates them. And your newfound solution can not work.

Comment: avoid using variable names that are C keywords.

Comment: sorry, My intention was not a duplicate question.

Comment: I edit my code to work now, and as you know scanf is work when SDL check, off condtion for safety.

Comment: I just noticed that I confused the case with the mode variable that I originally had to enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `goto`:

This will only exit the `while` loop.

```
while (true) { 
    ...
    if (some condition) {
        goto CLEANUP;
    }
    ...
}
CLEANUP:
...
```

---

### `exit()` the program:

```
while (true) {
    ...
    if (some condition) {
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
       
       /* OR, if in the `main()` function: */
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ....
}
```

---

### `abort()` the program:

```
while (true) { 
    ...
    if (some condition) {
        abort ();
    }
    ...
}
```

Some other alternatives, that will do much more than just exit the `while` loop, include:

- The `raise()` function.
- The `quick_exit()` function.
- The `_Exit()` function.
- The `_exit` function. (Note that this is not defined in the C standard, it is a POSIX extension)