# how to exit nested loops

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, break

i have something like

```
   while(playAgain==true)
   {
      cout<<"new game"<<endl; //i know 'using namespace std;' is looked down upon
      while(playerCard!=21)
      {
          *statements*
          if(decision=='n')
          {
              break
          }
       ...
      }
   }
```

but that break only breaks out of the first while loop when I want to break out of both of the loops

Comment: set a flag, check it, if set break again....

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257744/can-i-use-break-to-exit-multiple-nested-for-loops

Comment: You could use a `goto` statement which jumps to a label outside the loop.... **Of course im joking :)**. The best solution is to avoid the nested if (The if with the `break`) and put the condition (`decission == 'n'`) in the two loops.

Answer (score 8):

***Don't cook spaghetti*** and extract your loops into the function:

```
void foo(...) {
    while (...) {
        /* some code... */
        while (...) {
            if ( /* this loop should stop */ )
                break;
            if ( /* both loops should stop */ )
                return;
        }
        /* more code... */
    }
}
```

this decomposition will also yield cleaner code since instead of hundreds of lines of ugly procedural code, you will have neat functions at different levels of abstraction.

Comment: It has a shortfall when too many variables are used but defined outside of the loop (in the original function), which means you have to pass those many variables via `foo()'s` arguments

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two options to go.

1. Add the condition check in outer loop.

   `while ((playAgain==true) && (decision != '\n'))`
2. Simply use `goto`. People are often told never to use `goto` as if it's monster. But I'm not opposed to use it to exit multiple loops. It's clean and clear in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(playAgain==true && decision !='n' ){
                           ^^ add a condition
      cout<<"new game"<<endl; 
      while(playerCard!=21){
      *statements*
      if(decision=='n'){
          break
         }
     ...
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use goto:

```
   while(playAgain==true)
   {
      cout<<"new game"<<endl; //i know 'using namespace std;' is looked down upon
      while(playerCard!=21)
      {
          *statements*
          if(decision=='n')
          {
              goto label;
          }
       ...
      }
   }
   label: 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific to your case. When the user's decision is 'n', he doesn't want to play again. So just set `playAgain` to `false` and then break. Outer loop will be broken automatically.

```
while(playAgain==true){
   cout<<"new game"<<endl; //i know 'using namespace std;' is looked down upon
   while(playerCard!=21){
      *statements*
      if(decision=='n'){
         playAgain = false; // Set this to false, your outer loop will break automatically
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to avoid `goto` statement, you can write

```
while (a) {
    while (b) {
        if (c) {
            goto LABEL;
        }
    }
}
LABEL:
```