# C - Arrays. Change only specific values

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to search through an array, and only check specific values (the 4th,5th and so on)- ((0+n*4) and (3+n*4).
The first one found will be checked and if it has a value of 0 will it be changed to 1 and then the program should stop. If not it will try the next value and so on..
I have the following code, but it doesn't stop ..it makes all the values 1 at once..
Any suggestions?

```
        {
        for (i=0; i<(totalnumber); i++)
        {   for (n=0; n<((totalnumber)/4); n++)
            {   if (i==(0+(n*4)))
                {   if (array[i]==0)
                    {
                        array[i]=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                else if ((i==(3+(n*4))))
                {
                if (array[i]==0)
                {
                    array[i]=1;
                    break;
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

Using a single `break` statement only breaks out of the nearest loop. It doesnt break out of the outer `i` loop. So, change your code to break out of the outer loop too.

One other way is to use both counter variables `i`,`n` within the same for loop. That means, you only use `break` once to break out of the outer for loop.

I quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx)

> Within nested statements, the break statement terminates only the do, for, switch, or while statement that immediately encloses it. You can use a return or goto statement to transfer control elsewhere out of the nested structure.

This is related - [Can I use break to exit multiple nested for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257744/can-i-use-break-to-exit-multiple-nested-for-loops)