# How to go to next within for each loop

Tags: c++, foreach, c++-cli, continue

I recently needed to modify someone's code that used multiple `continue` cases in a `for each`.  The addition was a new control loop inside the `for each`, which promptly broke the `continue` logic.  Is there a good way to get the next list item in a such a loop without rewriting all of the continue cases?

```
// Additional control loops within the member function which cannot be 
// turned into functions due to native C++ data types.
{
    for each(KeyValuePair<String^,String^> kvp in ListOfItems) {
        do { // new condition testing code
           // a bunch of code that includes several chances to continue
        } while (!reachedCondition)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use break to exit multiple nested for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257744/can-i-use-break-to-exit-multiple-nested-for-loops)

Comment: If C++/CLI *does* support named loops, that renders the question trivial.  Just name the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` and `break` go to the inner most control loop.  I've used the iterator within a `for` loop.  So depending upon what your ListOfItems is (i.e. `SortedList` or `Dictionary` ...) you might be able to iterate instead of `continue`.

```
int i=0;
Dictionary^ d = gcnew Dictionary<string, string>();

for (IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>>^ e =  d->GetEnumerator();i< d->Count;i++) {
    // do stuff
    e->MoveNext();
}
```