# Is there a Pythonic way of activating 'else' in a 'for' loop, when a continue has hit?

Tags: python

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296044/opposite-of-python-for-else) didn't really answer my question.

I have a

```
reader = csv.reader(source)
for row in reader:
    if len(row[0]) > 23:
        # Do stuff
        continue
    if low > float(row[1]) > high:
        # Do stuff
        continue
    if low > float(row[2]) > high:
        # Do stuff
        continue
else:
    print('All', reader.line_num, 'read successfully.')
```

setup, but the `else` is executed despite me skipping in the `for` loop.

I'd rather that the else was only called if no `continue` was hit.

In order to clarify, the purpose of the code is to drop bad/malformed data rows in the CSV file. As such, malformed lines have individual error handling. Using 'else' as final notifier would, if possible be much more beautiful than working with flags.

Comment: You should explain with example input what you are expecting as output.

Comment: `else` is called if the for loop exits due to exhausting the iterator, you would need a `break` to avoid the `else` being called.

Comment: I think using a flag variable like `continued = True`, while not particularly pythonic, is the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that matters to `else` is whether or not the loop terminated because you reached the end of the iterable; it doesn't care what happens inside the loop.

If you want to have different behavior depending on if `continue` was ever called, then you have to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll have to keep track of rows skipped manually then.