# Why the else statement did not execute in the code?

Tags: python

```
search =int(input('enter the element to search'))
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if search==x:
        print('element is found')
        break
else:
    print('element is not found')
```

---

*why the else statement is not executed here as we know that adding else suite after for loop ,it gets executed anyway*

```
 enter the element to search4
    element is found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opposite of Python for ... else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296044/opposite-of-python-for-else)

Comment: The `else` statement for a `for` loop should have been called `nobreak`.

Answer (score 4):

The `else` part to the `for` doesn't get executed *anyway*.
It gets executed only when the loop completes fully and normally without breaking.

```
search = 4
for x in [1,2,3,5]:
    if search==x:
        print('element is found')
        break
    else:
        print('Element is not found (from if)')
else:
    print('element is not found (from for)')
```

Output:

```
Element is not found (from if)
Element is not found (from if)
Element is not found (from if)
Element is not found (from if)
element is not found (from for)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... we know that adding `else` suite after for loop, it gets executed anyway.

*You* may think that, most seasoned Python developers would not agree :-)

You misunderstand when the `else` is executed. Specifically, it is ***not*** executed when you `break` from the loop, which you are for the input value of `4`.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) for more detail, in particular, this bit:

> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

Answer (score -2):

> somehow I can feel what u want to do here, to achieve that u need to write as below instead!

```
search = int(input('enter the element to search\n'))
for x in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if search==x:
       print('element is found')
       break

if search!=x:
    print('element is not found')
```