# break two for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

is it possible to break out of two **for** loops in Python?
i.e.

```
for i in range(1,100):  
    for j in range(1,100):  
        break ALL the loops!
```

Comment: See PEP 3136: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, there is no nested `break` statement in python.

Instead, you can simplify your function, like this:

```
import itertools
for i,j in itertools.product(range(1, 100), repeat=2):
  break
```

.. or put the code into its own function, and use `return`:

```
def _helper():
   for i in range(1,100):
       for j in range(1,100):
           return
_helper()
```

.. or use an exception:

```
class BreakAllTheLoops(BaseException): pass
try:
   for i in range(1,100):
       for j in range(1,100):
           raise BreakAllTheLoops()
except BreakAllTheLoops:
    pass
```

.. or use for-else-continue:

```
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,100):
       break
    else:
       continue
    break
```

.. or use a flag variable:

```
exitFlag = False
for i in range(1,100):
    for j in range(1,100):
        exitFlag = True
        break
    if exitFlag:
        break
```

Comment: Another option that is missing, the [for/else/continue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150107/505154).

Comment: @F.J Added, thanks. I'm worrying a little bit about duplication, but this question seems easier to read than the old one.

Answer (score 5):

Several solutions were proposed in [PEP 3136](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/), but the BDFL [rejected it](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html):

> I'm rejecting it on the basis that code so complicated to require this
>   feature is very rare. In most cases there are existing work-arounds
>   that produce clean code, for example using 'return'. While I'm sure
>   there are some (rare) real cases where clarity of the code would
>   suffer from a refactoring that makes it possible to use return, this
>   is offset by two issues:
>
> 1. The complexity added to the language, permanently. This affects not only all Python implementations, but also every source analysis tool,
>      plus of course all documentation for the language.
> 2. My expectation that the feature will be abused more than it will be used right, leading to a net decrease in code clarity (measured across
>      all Python code written henceforth). Lazy programmers are everywhere,
>      and before you know it you have an incredible mess on your hands of
>      unintelligible code.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot specify how many loops to break. Put your code in a function and use `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: use a **flag** variable in the inner loop and set it to `True` when you use `break`. Then use it for `break`ing the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,100):
    breaking = false
    for j in range(1,100):
        if foundAReasonToBreak:  
            breaking = true
            break
    if breaking:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    for i in range(1,10):
        print i
        for j in range(1,10):
            if j == 5: raise AssertionError
            print j
except AssertionError:  
    pass

print "I'm free"
```

This is a little distasteful but it does seem to accomplish what you're asking.

**Edit:** I see @phihag posted something similar as I was experimenting.

Comment: Don't use existing exceptions for cases that are not the same at all as what the exception was originally intended for. Create your own.