# loop is not breaking when going through excel sheet using python

Tags: python

I would like to go to each excel file and in that specific sheet, find the text "Sen's slope:" and break the loop to find the row and column and then print the value adjacent to that text.

could anyone help me where i'm wrong in this code.?
any help is appreciated.

```
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook

excelfiles=[]
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if '.xlsm' in i:
        excelfiles.append(i)

cannotfiles=[]
slope=[]
for f in excelfiles:
    print f
    wb = open_workbook(f)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Mann-Kendall trend tests')
    j=0
    for j in range(0,50):
        i=0
        for i in range(0,50):
            print sheet.cell(i,j).value
            if sheet.cell(i,j).value == "Sen's slope:":
                break
    print sheet.cell(i,j+1).value
```

Thanks

Comment: python is reading past my string in cells (without breaking) and finally an error "array index out of range".

Comment: i'm guessing you are only breaking out of the inner loop

Comment: You have two problems here, the loop and the wrong assignment. In Python you simply don't need to declare the variable for the loop like in C or Java, so `j=0` and `i=0` are not needed. The second thing, you're breaking only the inner loop, thus the out loop will continue iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place two `if` statements here, one to break the *inner* loop and the second to break the *outer* loop:

```
for j in range(50):
    for i in range(50):
        print (sheet.cell(i,j).value)
        if sheet.cell(i,j).value == "Sen's slope:": break
    if sheet.cell(i,j).value == "Sen's slope:": break
```

When you break the the inner loop, the value of `j` will be the same value of the last iteration, the control flow will then go to the last line which is the line after the inner `for` loop and will evaluate the second `if` statement to break the outer loop.

Comment: thanks. it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You specified break to exit only the inner for loop
try the below code:

```
for j in range(0, 50):
    for i in range(0, 50):
        if "something":
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: it is actually going past cell with "Sen's slope" without recognising it and loop is not breaking.

Comment: @Vijaynitk: Did you change the `if` statement in Mani's code example to `if sheet.cell(i,j).value == "Sen's slope:"` ?

Comment: @Mani Kandan: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that you have a `for` in a `for`, and the break only breaks out of the inner `for`. You could move the print function inside one for loop, that also lets you detect multiple occurrences of "Sen's slope:". Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9038199/5151127) has a bunch of ways how you can break out of both loops.

Comment: how do i break of the whole loops? using exit? but then when i print cells value, it is actually going past that cell without recognising it.

Comment: In your code, it finds the entry, stops reading that row, and goes on the to next row. So it keeps reading past it.