# How to continue in nested loops in Python

Tags: python

How can you `continue` the parent loop of say two nested loops in Python?

```
for a in b:
    for c in d:
        for e in f:
            if somecondition:
                <continue the for a in b loop?>
```

I know you can avoid this in the majority of cases but can it be done in Python?

Comment: any reason to not just use `break` ?

Comment: Use `break` to leave the inner loop - this'll immediately continue in the outer loop.

Comment: There's another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python

Comment: @JonClements I've fixed the example to actually need the continue.

Comment: when nesting loops, you should conside this technique: [flatten nested loops](https://youtu.be/eJP8OSFZrJY).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

1. Break from the inner loop (if there's nothing else after it)
2. Put the outer loop's body in a function and return from the function
3. Raise an exception and catch it at the outer level
4. Set a flag, break from the inner loop and test it at an outer level.
5. Refactor the code so you no longer have to do this.

I would go with 5 every time.

Comment: one of the cases where PHP beats Python, since it does have level options for `break` and `continue` :)

Comment: I would consider #2 to be the standard way to implement #5, unless there is a completely different approach to the problem in context.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a bunch of hacky ways to do it:

1. Create a local function

   ```
   for a in b:
       def doWork():
           for c in d:
               for e in f:
                   if somecondition:
                       return # <continue the for a in b loop?>
       doWork()
   ```

   A better option would be to move doWork somewhere else and pass its state as arguments.
2. Use an exception

   ```
   class StopLookingForThings(Exception): pass

   for a in b:
       try:
           for c in d:
               for e in f:
                   if somecondition:
                       raise StopLookingForThings()
       except StopLookingForThings:
           pass
   ```

Answer (score 18):

You use `break` to break out of the inner loop and continue with the parent

```py
for a in b:
    for c in d:
        if somecondition:
            break # go back to parent loop
```

Answer (score 12):

```
from itertools import product
for a in b:
    for c, e in product(d, f):
        if somecondition:
            break
```

Answer (score 3):

use a boolean flag

```
problem = False
for a in b:
  for c in d:
    if problem:
      continue
    for e in f:
        if somecondition:
            problem = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at All the answers here its all different from how i do it\n
Mission:continue to while loop if the if condition is true in nested loop

```
chars = 'loop|ing'
x,i=10,0
while x>i:
    jump = False
    for a in chars:
      if(a = '|'): jump = True
    if(jump==True): continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = ["hello1", "hello2" , "world"]

for index,word in enumerate(lista):
    found = False
    for i in range(1,3):
        if word == "hello"+str(i):
            found = True
            break
        print(index)
    if found == True:
        continue
    if word == "world":
        continue
    print(index)
```

Now what's printed :

```
>> 1
>> 2
>> 2
```

This means that the word no.1 ( index = 0 ) appeard first (there's no way for something to be printed before the continue statement). The word no.2 ( index = 1 ) appeared second ( the word "hello1" managed to be printed but not the rest ) and the word no.3 appeard third what mean's that the words "hello1" and "hello2" managed to be printed before the for loop reached this said third word.

To sum up it's just using the found = False / True boolean and the break statement.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
#infinite wait till all items obtained
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for item in entries:
        if self.results.get(item,None) is None:
            print(f"waiting for {item} to be obtained")
            break #continue outer loop
    else:
        break
    #continue
```

I wish there could be a labeled loop ...