# Validating a CSV file's boolean values in Python

Tags: python, csv

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for i, v in enumerate(row):
            if not v in ['0','1']:
                print ("Skipping", row)
                print (i, "not a 0 or 1")
                continue
        print ("Good", row)
```

With the input:

```
x220:~/csv$ cat foo.csv
0,1,0
1,2,3
```

I wrote a simple Python program to check whether the CSV input has good 0 or 1 values. First row is valid, but not the second of foo.csv, since it has invalid "2" and "3" values.

First problem is the **`continue`** does not work here. I am not sure how to fix that issue. I could set a invalid boolean and have a `if invalid: continue` at the the end of validation phase, but that looks sucky to me somehow, especially if the rest of my validation code uses `continue`.

Is there other improvements you can suggest?

Comment: You want to skip the rest of the row rather than just one item? In which case you could just replace `continue` with `break`.

Comment: I want to skip the row if I notice any invalid-ness.

Comment: before if condition try to cast your number (v) to string , then check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to "continue" your outer loop, i.e. a situation like one of the following..

- [How to continue in nested loops in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829640/how-to-continue-in-nested-loops-in-python)
- [Python: Continuing to next iteration in outer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859072/python-continuing-to-next-iteration-in-outer-loop)

So something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for i, v in enumerate(row):
            if not v in ['0','1']:
                print ("Skipping", row)
                print (i, "not a 0 or 1")
                break
        else:
            print ("Good", row)
```

And an even shorter way if you don't need to log skipped rows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = (row for row in reader
            if all(v in ['0', '1'] for v in row))

    for row in rows:
        print ("Good", row)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the level of your for loops. Your 'continue' print statements say you're skipping a row, but your continue statement will only skip the most-inner loop, which is at the element level. You will always reach the print good row line.

Try using a boolean variable to note whether the row stayed good:

```
for row in reader:
    rowIsGood=true    
    for i, v in enumerate(row):
        if not v in ['0','1']:
            print ("Skipping", row)
            print (i, "not a 0 or 1")
            rowIsGood=false
            break
    if rowIsGood:
        print ("Good", row)
```

. --Edited the inner continue to a break, as that appears to be the desired behavior.

Comment: I'm aware of the boolean variable trick, but it just seems sucky to me.

Comment: You can also use the `else` clause for `for-loops` if you don't like booleans

Comment: To agree with you, hendry, I've never enjoyed this method, but there is no way of stacking continue statements. The subsequent continues wouldn't be reached. So information/data/signals must be passed backward out of the loop.