# Is there a way to skip a value from itertools.product loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-itertools

I'm making a script which compares the distance between two addresses, those addresses are stored in two different .csv files together combined with `itertools.product`.

Comparing is an `if` condition which checks if addresses are 1km away from each other.

Every address from `addresses1` needs to be compared with every address from `addresses2`.

If the address in `addresses1` is 1km away from the address in `addresses2` it **needs to move on the next comparing.** Because the lists are too long, it's wasting of time to wait to move on the next one. - And that's the problem.

I tried with `continue` but it's not working.

Let's say I have two lists of addresses:

```
addresses1 = ["Address1","Address2","Address3","Address4"]
addresses2 = ["compAddress1","compAddress2,"compAddress3","compAddress4","compAddress5"]

producted_list = list(itertools.product(addresses1, addresses2))

for a,b in producted_list:
    BLOCK OF CODE WITH GEOLOCATIONS

    if(distance == 1km):
        print("Addresses are within 1km from each other, move on next one")
        continue
```

Let's see how it's comparing:

```
a[0] -> b[0]
a[0] -> b[1]
a[0] -> b[2]
a[0] -> b[3]
a[0] -> b[4]

a[1] -> b[0]
a[1] -> b[1]
a[1] -> b[2]
a[1] -> b[3]
a[1] -> b[4]

a[2] -> b[0]
a[2] -> b[1]
a[2] -> b[2]
a[2] -> b[3]
a[2] -> b[4]
.
.
.
```

Let's say that `a[1]` is matched with `b[0]`, I want to immediately move on the `a[2]` without continuing with `a[1]` comparing with the rest of `b[]`

I've tried to use the code from Eric https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829934/11417917

with

```
for a in b:
    def doWork():
        for c in d:
                if somecondition:
                    return # <continue the for a in b loop?>
    doWork()
```

But it's not working, it interrupts, either it needs changing.

Comment: You're probably best writing two loops instead of trying to filter the products.

Comment: It's the same thing, not working if I use two for loops like in other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the applicable solution from the duplicate you cited.  You need to `break` the inner loop; this will naturally continue the outer loop:

```
for a in addresses_1:
    for b in addresses_2:
        if distance(a, b) <= 1.00:
            print(a, b, "are within 1 km")
            break
```

Comment: Finally working. Really unbelievable... I cannot imagine how a stupid miss.

Comment: Most of us *can* imagine -- we've been there.  How do you think I recognized this one?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just write two loops and break out of the inner loop to continue the outer loop:

```
addresses1 = ["Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4"]
addresses2 = ["compAddress1", "compAddress2", "compAddress3", "compAddress4", "compAddress5"]

for a in addresses1:
    for b in addresses2:
        BLOCK OF CODE WITH GEOLOCATIONS

        if(distance == 1km):
            print("Addresses are within 1km from each other, move on next one")
            break
```