# Leaving the for / while loop if certain conditions are met

Tags: python

I wrote a set of codes to calculate a Diophantine equation:

```
bestSoFar = 0     
packages = (6,9,20)   
numMc = 0
guess= 0
possibn = []
for n in xrange(1, 150):   
   for a in xrange(0, (n/ packages[0]) +1):
       for b in xrange(0,(n/ packages[1]) +1):
           c = (n - packages[0]* a - b * packages[1]) / packages[-1]
           numMc = packages[0] *a + packages[1] * b + packages[-1] * c
           if numMc == n and n not in possibn:
               possibn.append(n)
               print possibn
               if len(possibn) >6 and possibn [-1] - possibn[-6] == 5:
                  bestSoFar = n
                  break
```

---

The original problem set is designed by the MIT course. Basically it is to calculate the number of McNuggets that could be bought by arranging the ratio of packages-in-different-size ( McDonald does 6,9,20 McNuggets in a package). Say, 21 McNuggets could be bought by buying two 6-McNuggets and one 9-McNuggets. if the number of McNuggets are possible to be bought in exact quantity of packages, I store them into a list. It is found that if 6 consecutive numbers are also possible to be bought in exact quantity, the remained numbers could also be possible.

From my code the result of bestSoFar=149 while the expected answer is 40. The reason would be that it keeps looping until n reaches 149. I would like to stop right at 40 ( with the break statement). However, it fails and I am seeking the advices for you all. Also, if there is anyway to program the problem faster/easier, I am happy to know and learn it too.

Thank you so much. 
Casey

Comment: See [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not supposed to use a function, just assign a variable to cause breaks out of the other loops.

```
bestSoFar = 0     
packages = (6,9,20)   
numMc = 0
guess= 0
possibn = []
finished = False
for n in xrange(1, 150):   
   for a in xrange(0, (n/ packages[0]) +1):
       for b in xrange(0,(n/ packages[1]) +1):
           c = (n - packages[0]* a - b * packages[1]) / packages[-1]
           numMc = packages[0] *a + packages[1] * b + packages[-1] * c
           if numMc == n and n not in possibn:
               possibn.append(n)
#               print possibn
               if len(possibn) >6 and possibn [-1] - possibn[-6] == 5:
                  bestSoFar = n
                  finished = True
                  break
   if finished: break
print bestSoFar
```

Comment: when I add a print bestSoFar after if finished, it keeps printing the list
it returns the result as below:
0
0
0
0
0
[6]
0
0
0
[6,9]
.....
up to [6,9,12...40]
but I want the ans 40 only!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a function and `return`:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def solve(*packages):
    bestSoFar = 0
    numMc = 0
    guess= 0
    possibn = []
    for n in xrange(1, 150):
       for a in xrange(0, (n / packages[0]) + 1):
           for b in xrange(0, (n / packages[1]) + 1):
               c = (n - packages[0] * a - b * packages[1]) / packages[-1]
               numMc = packages[0] * a + packages[1] * b + packages[-1] * c
               if numMc == n and n not in possibn:
                   possibn.append(n)
                   print possibn
                   if len(possibn) > 6 and possibn [-1] - possibn[-6] == 5:
                      return n
    return bestSoFar

x = solve(6, 9, 20)
print(x)
```

Comment: yes a function would do
however, the course does not introduce function when this problem set was introduced.. 
Thank you for your ans!

Answer (score -1):

I am not actually clear on what you are expecting. But, what i see is you want to break out of everything. The break which you have given only exits inner loop. Put another `break` statement outside the inner loop and inside first loop.

Comment: he need to repeat the `if` statement if he want to do what you say so he will broke `DRY`, @Rob gave the same solution that you suggest but in clever way.

Comment: Let me clarify:
my expected ans is to return the number "40"
as the numbers  35,36,37,38,39,40 ( 6 consecutive) would works.