# Python Selenium infinite loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I'm trying to study customers behavior. Basically, I have information on customer's loyalty points activities data (e.g. how many points they have earned, how many points they have used, how recent they have used/earn points etc). I'm using R to conduct this analysis

I'm just wondering how should I go about segmenting customers based on the above information? I'm trying to apply the RFM concept then use K-means to segment my customers(although I have a few more variables than just R,F,M , as i have recency,frequency and monetary on both points earn and use, as well as other ratios and metrics) . Is this a good way to do this?

Essentially I have two objectives:
1. To segment customers
2. Via segmenting customers, identify customers behavior(e.g.customers who spend all of their points before churning), provided that segmentation is the right method for such task?

Clustering <- kmeans(RFM_Values4,centers = 10)

Please enlighten me, need some guidance on the best methods to tackle such problems.

Comment: Please fix your indentation so that it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: @R.Murray , thanks I copied straight from Python shell so the indentation should be ok??

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whole `with` structure should be indented so that it is part of the `while True` loop. Copying straight across from IDLE often doesn't work properly.

Comment: @R.Murray, unfortunately i don't have an editor yet.will get one soon. Are you able to tell where it went wrong?

Comment: Now you have a while true and no way to break out of it. Breaks only stop the smallest level of for/while available, in order to break out of several levels of for/while please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python

Comment: without the while true i'm afraid i wont be able to loop though the existing elements.

Comment: @IV_Z, but you need to define a case to stop the loop, otherwise it will be infinite

Comment: you loop through the list of elements by `for sub_list in (driver.find_elements...` You don't need `While` loop at all

Answer (score 0):

Your `attempts` is always less then 5 because there is no variable increment. So your loop is infinite

Comment: thanks. I tried removing the attempts but the loop is still infinite if one of the element im tring to locate is not present:  e.g. if the following element does not exist the program will just keep printing element 1 and 2 non stop       
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]")

Comment: This xpath is very-very bad:) You should never use absolute xpaths

Comment: unfortunately the site has thousands of sub/sub div element at child level making any element find function not so user friendly

Comment: so use just a child locators

Comment: sorry I have only been using python and programming for 3 weeks I need some time for some research :)