# Python 'break' behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, string, loops, substring, break

People who have given an interview test maybe familiar with the "substring" question. The question is, as follows:

"For *string* find the largest substring from the right that has at *most* two different characters.

I have written a small code to achieve this:

```
def generate_substring(givenstring):
    givenstring_list = []

    for i in range(0, len(givenstring)):
        for j in range(0, len(givenstring)):
            if i != j:
                givenstring_list.append(givenstring[i:j])

    return_list = [givenstring_list[i] for i in range(0,len(givenstring_list)) if givenstring_list[i] != '']

    return reversed(return_list)


def main():
    code_input = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
    substrings_list = generate_substring(code_input)
    temp = ""

    for substrings in substrings_list:
        for i in range(1, len(substrings)):
            if substrings[i - 1] != substrings[i]:
                temp = substrings
                break #Notice This!

    print(temp)


main()
```

Notice the `for` loop with a `break`. I don't know why is this, but `break` cannot manage to break out of the loop. Therefore I get the *leftmost* substring instead. Why is that?

Comment: Before I read your entire block of code let me ask: did you expect it to break out of _both_ loops? Because it won't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/189645/3001761

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: C# does, I thought Python would.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Fixed. Thanks. How do I tag my question as solved?

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate of the question I mentioned, I think that would be automatically marked as you're the questioner.