# When breaking out of a nested loop, how do I make it so that the inner loop isn't ignored in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested

In a nested loop, after breaking out of the inner loop and going to the top loop it skips the parameters of the inner loop. Why and how can I fix this?

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i == j:
            print('Same Number')
        break
```

This code only prints 'Same Number' once. When 1 = 1. I'm not sure why j never changes but i does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break out of multiple loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops)

Comment: @Selcuk I saw that earlier today and attempted to replicate it by adding an else and continue statement, but the output was still the same. I also don't know how to refactor (I'm still fairly newish to python).

Comment: First this my first attempt at ansering so sorry if I’m doing it wrong.

You are breaking out of the outer loop “i”  not the inner loop “j” 

See for a better explanation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602620/how-to-break-out-of-nested-loops-in-python

try indenting break one more time like this.for i in range(5):
 # print(i)
for j in range(5):
 if (i==j):
  print("same number")
  # print(i,j)
  break

Comment: Sorry couldn't get that to format right. just indent break one more time so you are only breaking out of the inner loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written right now, the inner loop will always break on the first iteration (when `i = 0`). This is why you are only seeing it print once, the outer loop is looping 5 times, however the inner loop only ever gets through the first iteration before hitting `break`.

See below, the `break` line should be nested inside the if statement so it only breaks from the inner loop when the two numbers match.

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i == j:
            print('Same Number')
            break
```