# Breaking outside the loop - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, break

This might be obvious to others.

Using `a > 10` breaks the `loop` as expected, however `a == 10` doesn't. Why is this happening? I am using `Python 3.5`.

The code snippet:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('1.jpg')
px = im.load()
width, height = im.size

for a in range(width):
   for b in range(height):
      if a == 10:
         break
      print(a, b)
```

---

**Edit:**
I trying to stop the iteration when the image width has reached 10. The output looks like this:

```
...
9 477
9 478
9 479
10 0
10 1
10 2
10 3
...
```

Comment: What is your output, and what was the expected output? Using that if inside the second loop is a bit strange because a's value doesn't change while in that loop.

Comment: Your `break` statement breaks out of the inner loop. If you use `a == 10`, it will only break that one time when `a` is 10 and the next iteration of the outer loop will cause it to be run again. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What happens if you run `if int(a) == 10` ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Same things, keeps on going. I think the issues is as Yegers pointed out that I should break within the context of the first loop.

Comment: There are quite a few posts on breaking out of outer loops from an inner loop, which are worth looking at i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python

Comment: But how is `10 0` printed out anyway? No matter which loop is broken, the print statement shouldn't be reached when a equals 10.

Comment: @RobinKoch any of the solutions mentioned above work. The `10 0` is not printed anymore if I break in the context of the first loop.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Is that the output *before* you inserted the `break` statement in the first place..?

Comment: Yes, it's the original output for the code in my question.

Comment: Read my question again. Your answer is contradictional. I asked if *that* code in your question (*including* the `break` produces *that* output in your question (including the lines `10 0`, `10 1`, ...). Because it should not and it does not on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the `a == 10` in the outer loop because now it will only break the inner loop.

```
for a in range(width):
   if a == 10:
      break
   for b in range(height):
      print(a, b)
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to put it behind the `for b in range(..` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `if` outside the inner loop:

```
for a in range(width):
   if a == 10:
      break
   for b in range(height):
      print(a, b)
```

You only left the inner loop and the out one kept running; so when a reach 11, the inner loop starting printing again.

With `a > 10` you didn't have that problem as all inner loops immediately stopped, but they did all get started.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a break statement, you can use `min(...)` to predetermine how many times to loop, for example:

```
for a in range(min(10, width)):
    for b in range(height):
        print(a, b)
```

This run 10 times, with values of `a` from 0 to 9 - unless the width is less than 10, in which case it loops `width` times.

Comment: This is really helpful to know.

Comment: @FGran using `break` can result in spaghetti code, something like this is much more pythonic, elegant and readable :)