# Breaking out of multiple nested while loops

Tags: python

If I have a body of code that looks like this:

```
for ship in ships.shipLengths.key():
    while(True):
        # Code
        while(True):
            # Code
            while(True):
                # Code
```

If I am currently in the 3rd while loop is there a way for me to get back to the first while loop?

Comment: Please do not write code like that, it has terrible readability. Use functions in place of each loop's body.

Comment: write your code in functions, so you can use return to exit multiple loops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Comment: using break in the next loops

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Aluan and @Daniel that is not a good practice to write the code that way.

Anyway, if you still want to do it, here is a way:

```
x = True
for ship in ships.shipLengths.key():
    while condition1:
        # Code
        while condition2 and x:
            # Code
            while condition3 and x:
                # Code
                if goto_1st_while:
                    x = False
                    continue
                # The code here will not run when goto_1st_while is True
            if not x:
                continue
            # The code here will not run when goto_1st_while is True
```

Comment: continue is not good, with continue you cannot exit from the loop but only to continue its running

Comment: Yes, but when x is False, you will exit.