# Skip enumeration and go to the next in Python

Tags: python, loops, enumerate, continue

```
def worker(worker_comment):
    time.sleep(vote_delay)
    try:
        for (k, v) in enumerate(account):
            worker_steem = Steem(keys=posting_key)
            upvote_comment = worker_steem.get_content(worker_comment.identifier)

            # Checking if Post is flagged for Plagarism & Spam
            names = ['blacklist', 'fubar-bdhr']
            if ('-' in str(upvote_comment['author_reputation'])):
                print("@%s %s ====> Upvote Skipped - Author rep too low")
                return False
            for avote in upvote_comment['active_votes']:
                if (avote['voter'] in names and avote['percent'] < 0):
                    print("@%s %s ====> Upvote Skipped - Flagged by blacklist or Fubar-bdhr")
                    return False

            # Checking if there is markings from Cheetah or Steemcleaners:
            names = ['cheetah', 'steemcleaners']
            for avote in upvote_comment['active_votes']:
                if (avote['voter'] in names):
                    print("@%s %s ====> Post Marked by SteemCleaners or Cheetah")
                    return False

            # Checking if the voting power is over 60%:
            if (mainaccount['voting_power'] < 60):
                print("Not Enough Voting Power")
                return False

            # Checking if we already voted for this post:
            names = account[k]
            for avote in upvote_comment['active_votes']:
                if (avote['voter'] in names):
                    print("@%s %s ====> Post Upvoted already by", account[k])
                    return False

            # UPVOTING THE POST
            upvote_comment.vote(100, voter=account[k])

            # Upvote has now been done and it will now print a message to your screen:
            print(upvote_comment, " ====> UPVOTED by", account[k])
            print("Voting Power Left:", mainaccount['voting_power'])
            upvote_history.append(upvote_comment.identifier)
    except:
        print("ERROR - Upvoting failed for", account[k])
        print("We have probably already upvoted this post before the author edited it.")
        print(str(e))
```

Hi, 
I am working on a `voting bot` for a Reddit-like use. This bot controls 6 accounts. The problem I'm running into is when I run the section of code that checks if one of my accounts have already voted for the post.

Let's say account 5 has already voted for the post:

The current code stops the enumeration altogether, so account 6 never gets a chance to run through the checks.

If I change the `return False` to `continue`, account 5 attempts to vote and because it has already voted, the exception also stops the script altogether.

I have tried `break`, `pass`, etc. I'm thinking now that I may have an indentation problem. Surely it is an easy fix and I'm just missing something.

Comment: 4 spaces never killed anybody...

Comment: not really sure what you're talking about

Comment: I'm saying your code is a headache to read because you alternate between 1 and 2 spaces for indentation. Usually, 4 is explicitly recommended by the style guide for this reason.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I copied and pasted from my editor and I don't think it translated right. Any ideas on what I did wrong here (aside from spacing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for continue rather than break.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue
As continue only breaks out of the inner for, you might be able to re-structure the inner for as a generator.

```
 if account[k] in [avote['voter'] for avote in upvote_comment['active_votes']]:
    print("@%s %s ====> Post Upvoted already by",  account[k])
    continue
```

I'm assuming that account[k] will only give one name here?

Comment: '# Checking if we already voted for this post:'
            'names = account[k]'
            for avote in upvote_comment['active_votes']:
                if (avote['voter'] in names):
                    print("@%s %s ====> Post Upvoted already by", account[k])
                    return False

So in the instance above, I changed return False to continue, but continue just puts it into the for loop above the if loop, which leads it to the 'upvote_comment.vote(100, voter=account[k])'

Comment: You're right, continue only continues with the innermost loop. I've added a differrent method of checking the voter account which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem I have is that if I 'return False', the enumeration stops and any iterations that have not run, won't run. I don't have a problem checking the voter account, it's just that I can't figure out a way to skip to the next enumeration when it comes back already voted.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say continue. I've corrected the code above.

Comment: By the way, this looks like it will vote with all (six) of the accounts (except any that have already voted). Is that what you wanted? (Just curious).

Comment: I should point out there are other ways you can avoid the nested for. I believe the standard recommendation is to refactor the inner for into a separate function. That way the return doesn't exit the main function, and you can test the result of calling this function in the main loop body. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python